# What does "this" mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, what does `this` means and when it is used?

Comment: the current element...
example <input type="text" onclick="this.value='abcde'" value="" />

this textbox will contain abcde when you click on it...

Comment: the concept of 'this' is JavaScript is, imho, one of the most complicated subjects of the language.  I would highly recommend reading up on it if you intend on doing much JavaScript.  And, when you think you understand, go back and read about it again, because if you're like me you didn't actually understand the first time you thought you understood.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: @Matt ya, you are right:) We all are over-confident people.

Comment: concept of this is explained here https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript is very special and powerful. It can mean just about anything. I cover some of it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html), but it's really worth finding a good tutorial on JavaScript and spending some time with it.

Let's look at jQuery's use of it first, then talk about it more generally in JavaScript (a bit).

### In jQuery, specifically

In code written with jQuery, `this` *usually* refers to the DOM element that's the subject of the function being called (for instance, in an event callback).

Example jQuery event callback (what `this` is is covered in [the `.bind` docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)):

```
$("div").click(function() {
    // Here, `this` will be the DOM element for the div that was clicked,
    // so you could (for instance) set its foreground color:
    this.style.color = "red";

    // You'll frequently see $(this) used to wrap a jQuery object around the
    // element, because jQuery makes lots of things a lot simpler. You might
    // hide the element, for example:
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Similarly, various jQuery functions that act on all of the elements matched by the current jQuery selector can optionally accept a function, and when that function gets called, `this` is again the DOM element in question — for instance, the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function allows this:

```
// Find all divs inside the `foo` element, and set
// their content to their CSS class name(s)
// (Okay, so it's a hokey example)
$("#foo div").html(function() {
    return this.className;
});
```

Another place jQuery uses `this` is in the callback on [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
jQuery.each(a, function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

...which will alert "one", then "two", then "three". As you can see, this is a totally different usage of `this`.

(Confusingly, jQuery has two functions called `each`, the one above which is on the jQuery/$ function itself and always called that way [`jQuery.each(...)` or `$.each(...)`], and a different one on jQuery *instances* [objects] rather than the jQuery/$ function iself. [Here are the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for the other one, I don't discuss the other one in this answer because it uses `this` the same way `html` and event callback do, and I wanted to show a *different* use of `this` by jQuery.)

### Generically in JavaScript

<s>`this` refers to an object.</s> *Update:* As of ES5's strict mode, that's no longer true, `this` can have any value. The value of `this` within any given function call is determined by *how the function is called* (not where the function is defined, as in languages like C# or Java). The most common way to set up `this` when calling a function is by calling the function via a property on the object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {
    alert(this.firstName);
};
obj.firstName = "Fred";
obj.foo(); // alerts "Fred"
```

There, because we called `foo` via a property on `obj`, `this` was set to `obj` for the duration of the call. But don't get the impression that `foo` is in any way married to `obj`, this works just fine:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {
    alert(this.firstName);
};
obj.firstName = "Fred";
obj.foo(); // alerts "Fred"

var differentObj = {};
differentObj.firstName = "Barney";
differentObj.bar = obj.foo; // Not *calling* it, just getting a reference to it
differentObj.bar(); // alerts "Barney"
```

In fact, `foo` isn't intrinsically tied to *any* object at all:

```
var f = obj.foo; // Not *calling* it, just getting a reference to it
f(); // Probably alerts "undefined"
```

There, since we didn't call `f` via an object property, `this` wasn't explicitly set. When `this` isn't explicitly set, it defaults to the global object (which is `window` in browsers). `window` probably doesn't have a property `firstName`, and so we got "undefined" in our alert.

There are other ways to call functions and set what `this` is: By using the function's `.call` and `.apply` functions:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    alert(this.firstName);
    alert(arg1);
    alert(arg2);
}

var obj = {firstName: "Wilma"};
foo.call(obj, 42, 27); // alerts "Wilma", "42", and "27"
```

`call` sets `this` to the first argument you give it, and then passes along any other arguments you give it to the function it's calling.

`apply` does exactly the same thing, but you give it the arguments for the function as an array instead of individually:

```
var obj = {firstName: "Wilma"};
var a   = [42, 27];
foo.apply(obj, a); // alerts "Wilma", "42", and "27"
//             ^-- Note this is one argument, an array of arguments for `foo`
```

Again, though, there's a lot more to explore about `this` in JavaScript. The concept is powerful, a bit deceptive if you're used to how some other languages do it (and not if you're used to some others), and worth knowing.

Here are some examples of `this` not referring to an object in ES5's strict mode:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";   // Strict mode

    test("direct");
    test.call(5, "with 5");
    test.call(true, "with true");
    test.call("hi", "with 'hi'");

    function test(msg) {
        console.log("[Strict] " + msg + "; typeof this = " + typeof this);
    }
})();
```

Output:

```
[Strict] direct; typeof this = undefined
[Strict] with 5; typeof this = number
[Strict] with true; typeof this = boolean
[Strict] with 'hi'; typeof this = string
```

Whereas in loose mode, all of those would have said `typeof this = object`; [live copy](http://jsbin.com/ukiMIsI/1).

Comment: 0
down vote
Here is how i would explain it, simply:

this refers to the object that called the function. Since differentObj called foo(), this will point to differentObj. Since f was defined in the global scope, its a method of the window object, so this points to window. Since the window object does not have a property firstName, this.firstName returns undefined

Fun fact: anything defined in the global scope, which is the top layer/level, becomes a property of the window object (global scope = window object).

Comment: @ryanwaite28: *"this refers to the object that called the function"* No, it doesn't. Objects don't call methods, code does; in JavaScript, code is only loosely linked to objects. When code calls methods, it sets the value of `this`, explicitly or implicitly, to whatever it likes -- in strict mode, it may not even be an object reference, it could be a primitive value.

Comment: Crowder technically yes. But for the sake of explaining it in a way people can understand, i said objects. But thanks for add the abstract details. "this" can literally refer to anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can i add edit the snippet and put them in stack snippet ?

Comment: @brk: Do you mean you want to edit the answer to turn the code blocks into runnable snippets? If so: Go for it, and thank you!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes i mean that

Answer (score 6):

**The this Keyword**

> In JavaScript, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the JavaScript code.

The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.The value of this, when used in an object, is the object itself.
The this keyword in an object constructor does not have a value. It is only a substitute for the new object.The value of this will become the new object when the constructor is used to create an object.

**Note that this is not a variable. It is a keyword. You cannot change the value of this.**

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i would explain it, simply:

`this` refers to the `object` ***that called*** the `function`.

so looking at this:

```
var foo = {
  name: "foo",
  log: function(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

var bar = {
  name: "bar"
}
bar.log = foo.log;
bar.log();
```

the bar object stores a reference of foo's log method into it's own log property **for itself**. now when bar calls its log method, this will point to bar because the method was called upon by the bar object.

this works for any other object, even the window object. if you call a function via the global scope, this will point to the window object.

by using the bind or call methods of a function, you can explicitly define what the object `this` will refer to during execution.

Fun fact: anything defined in the `global scope`, which is the top layer/level, becomes a property of the `window object` (global scope = window object).

Answer (score 1):

Top Google result for "javascript this": http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

**Edit:** I think the key sentence is:

"In JavaScript "this" always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that the function is a method of."

Quirksmode is (generally*) excellent, worth reading the whole article in detail.

*Apparently this statement is not necessarily correct, see T.J. Crowder's comment below.

Comment: not in javascript.. this in jquery.. thanks anyway! :D

Comment: jQuery *is* written in Javascript. Any jQuery code is also Javascript

Comment: *"'In JavaScript "this" always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that the function is a method of.'"* Wow, I hope the rest of the article is better than that. That quote perpetuates a distructive myth, not up to quirksmode's usual standards.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you explain the myth or link to more info about you what you mean?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski: Two posts on my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html). :-)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword this acts as a placeholder, and will refer to whichever object called that method when the method is actually used in Java Script