# what is the meaning of word this near the property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm a newcomerin JavaScript language.
I started to see some examples of JavaScript code.

and i cant understand the following code segment:

```
function Employee(name,salary)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.salary=salary;

  this.paycheck=function()
  {
   var monthly=this.salary/12;
   document.write(this.name+ ": " +monthly);
  };
} 
var emp= new Employee("Fred",10000);
emp.paycheck();
```

My question: what is the meaning of word **this** near the property inside class  (i.e.  ,this.name=name; this.salary=salary; )?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a good explanation of 'this': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `this` could be explained as meaning "properties that apply to *this* instance". Since `Employee` is a constructor function (you create instances of it using the `new` operator), every instance has its own values for those properties:

```
var me = new Employee("James", 2000000); //Instance of Employee
console.log(me.name); //Prints James

var you = new Employee("Michael", 2000000); //Another instance
console.log(you.name); //Prints Michael
```

Note that this also means every instance of `Employee` has its own copy of the `paycheck` method. This is not particularly efficient, as a separate copy of the function has to be stored in memory for every instance of the object. You could instead declare the method on the `prototype` of the `Employee` object, which would mean the method would be shared between all instances.

Answer (score 1):

> In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're
>   executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.
>   When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its
>   owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of
>   JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element
>   it belongs to.

For further reading see these links:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/
http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the calling context of the function.

Its value will be different based on how a function is invoked.

In your case, because `Employee` is invoked using `new`, it's a reference to the new object being constructed.

So when you do...

```
this.name=name;
```

...what's happening is that the new object you're creating is being assigned a property `name`, and its value is being set to whatever was passed to the `name` parameter of the function.

---

Here's one way to demonstrate it.

Simplify your function like this...

```
var foo;

function Employee() {
    foo = this;
}
```

So now all `Employee` does is set its `this` value to the outer variable `foo`.

Now lets create a new object

```
var bar = new Employee();
```

So `bar` has been assigned whatever `Employee` returned. If `this` is the new object constructed, and we assigned it to `foo`, then `foo` and `bar` should have the same object.

```
foo === bar; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `Employee` function is used a *constructor*. When the `new Employee()` syntax is used (as opposed to simply calling `Employee()`), `this` refers to an object that you are about to create, which is later assigned to `emp` variable.

Answer (score 1):

it's a definition of properties inside the class.
You can read short information about it here http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

**this** always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing