# What 'this' means inside a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read a portion of code about creating a service in angularjs, I don't understand what "this" means in this situation (`this.uploadFile = function (files)`)

```
recipesApp.service('uploadsService', function ($http) {
    var code = '';
    var fileName = '';

    this.uploadFile = function (files) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        //Take the first selected file
        fd.append("image", files[0]);

        var promise = $http.post('/uploads/uploadFile.json', fd, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).then(function (response) {
                code = response.data.code;
                fileName = response.data.fileName;
                return{
                    code: function () {
                        return code;
                    },
                    fileName: function () {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                };
            });
        return promise;
    };
});
```

Comment: Question is a duplicate.

See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196018/1209020

Comment: Also this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` points to the service itself.

```
recipesApp.service('uploadsService', function ($http) {
```

That function is a constructor. When called with `new`, what angular does, `this` refers to the created instance of the `uploadsService`.

```
this.uploadFile = function (files) {
```

So that line adds the method `uploadFile` to the `uploadService`.

Answer (score 0):

It points to the function scope. Nothing special for an angular service.

In your specific case, it points to the function scope of your

```
function( $http ) {
    var code = '';
    ...
}
```

function. For example you can use `this.code` to access the `code` variable in the same scope.

However if you go into any inner function such as a callback, `this` will point to the scope of that function and you will not be able to point to parent variables using `this`.

With `this.uploadFile = function(file){...}` you are defining a function variable in the context, so that you access 'uploadsService' from another place in your application and you will be able to use

`uploadsService.uploadFile();`