# How to get 'this' in a function referring to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Amongst other things, I have read:

- [what-does-this-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)
- [you-must-remember-this](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [mythical-methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

but they haven't solved 'this' problem I'm having with a piece of JavaScript.

I have a Section object that gets passed some XML which it uses to populate the section. In the Section object I append a `div` which has a specified index. The resulting jQuery object is pushed into a `sections` Array. The following code is from the Section object code:

```
sections.push($('#section' + p_sectionIndex));
this.showSection = function() {
    this.show();
}
this.hideSection = function() {
    this.hide();
}
sections[sections.length-1].on('show', this.showSection.call(sections[sections.length-1]));
sections[sections.length-1].on('hide', this.hideSection.call(sections[sections.length-1]));
```

Elsewhere I call `sections[index].trigger('hide');` and `sections[index].trigger('show');`

The first of the links I mentioned above seemed to suggest `this` in a function depends on HOW it's called and that you could pass a reference to `this` into the function by using `call`. I know the `showSection` and `hideSection` function ARE being triggered - I just can't get the `this` in those functions to refer to the jQuery objects in the `sections` Array.

I have tried multiple variations of the above (excluding the `call`, using `$(this)` in the functions, adding the `showSection` and `hideSection` functions to the jQuery object - amongst others) but I'm kind of out of ideas.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think swapping sections[sections.length-1] with sections.eq(sections.length-1) should work

Comment: Sorry, but that gets an "[object Array] has no method 'eq'" error.

Comment: Of course, it's an array.. stupid me, sorry

Comment: `sections[sections.length-1].on('show', this.showSection)` with `this.showSection = function() { $(this).show(); };` would be what you are after according to your explanation. If it's not, you have to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in an event handler is the element node that the event was bound to. If you want a jQuery object wrapping that node, use `$(this)`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b36M6/

This of course assumes you revert back to the correct way of passing a function to the event binding.

Comment: +1 This is correct. I missed that the methods weren't wrapping the DOM element, though that's only part of the problem.

Comment: If you could let me know what is the correct way of passing a function to the event binding, that would be great, thanks. I have tried using $(this) in the functions - it doesn't generate any errors, but it also doesn't show the section.

Comment: My fiddle shows that, so does coookiemonster's answer. If using the code from my fiddle doesn't work, then the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by that set of terms. Do you mean 'don't use an Array for the sections'?

Comment: No, you can use an array if you wish. It's a bit weird, but it will work.

Comment: OK, so what is it that you mean? I'm keen to learn. I've been looking at .map on the jQuery docs, but not making a great deal of progress. How would YOU 'store' a set of dynamically generated elements for easy, specific reference later? Note, I am not selecting these elements from html - I create them by appending them to the '.container' div and then push them into the 'sections' Array as shown above.

Comment: I would store them in jQuery object. To add a new element to a jquery object, use `theObj.add(newElement)`

Comment: well, i would actually store an array of dom nodes, and do the event binding when you create the element rather than later on the array.

Comment: The problem is some elements need to trigger events in elements that haven't been created yet so, as it is currently set up, I need to add the events after all the elements are present. But I've figured out what the problem was - Your suggestion made me think there was something fundamental that I was totally misunderstanding (I couldn't understand why a jQuery object stored in an Array wouldn't be treated the same way). Turns out I'd set the opacity to 0. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.call()`, you're invoking the function immediately.

Since you want `this` to refer to the element, bound, just pas the function itself.

```
sections[sections.length-1].on('show', this.showSection);
sections[sections.length-1].on('hide', this.hideSection);
```

Now `this` in the `showSection` and `hideSection` methods will refer to the `sections[]` member to which it was bound.

I assume `"show"` and `"hide"` are some sort of custom events.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said - That's what I had originally (and I've just tried it again) and it doesn't work. That's what got me looking more into what 'this' is referring to. Thanks for the reply though. Any other ideas will be well received!

Comment: I am trying to use the show and hide functions on the jQuery object in the sections Array.

Comment: @moosefetcher: Not sure what you mean. The `.on()` method will set the value of `this` in whatever function it's given to the element to which it was bound. Should work just fine.

Comment: I have taken out both the .calls and the reference in brackets after them, left everything else the same. It doesn't work. Any clue as to why?

Comment: @moosefetcher: I missed that your functions were not wrapping the `this` in a jQuery object. The value of `this` is going to be a DOM element, so you'd need `$(this).show();`. I would wonder why you're using an Array for these jQuery objects in the first place. That's not typical, since a jQuery object is an Array-like object anyway.