# remove class and add class on single element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table type structure made of `DIV` elements.
I have made a expand/collapse type list.

I have this icon that i want to change if it expands and  reset it back if I collapse the list.
The two icons are linked to 2 classes.

```
$('.rowHead_but i', this ).removeClass('icon-double-angle-down');
```

and

```
$('.rowHead_but i', this ).addClass('icon-double-angle-up');
```

Okay it removes the class successfully and adds the new class, but it does it for all rows.

I only want `this` row to be affected.

What Im I doing wrong?

> ```
> <div class="notificationDetail">
> <div class="header">
>     <div class="Collapse"> 
>         <div class="rowHead1"><span>2014-10-10</span></div> 
>         <div class="rowHead_but"><i class="icon-double-angle-down"></i></div> 
>     </div>
>   </div>
>  <div class="header">
>     <div class="Collapse"> 
>         <div class="rowHead2"><span>2014-10-10</span></div> 
>         <div class="rowHead_but"><i class="icon-double-angle-down"></i></div> 
>     </div>
>   </div>
>  <div class="header">
>     <div class="Collapse"> 
>         <div class="rowHead3"><span>2014-10-10</span></div> 
>         <div class="rowHead_but"><i class="icon-double-angle-down"></i></div> 
>     </div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

JQuery code

```
    $('.notificationDetail').on('click','.header', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();



        $(function() {

            var classTst_down = $('.rowHead_but i', this ).hasClass( "icon-double-angle-down" );
            var classTst_up = $('.rowHead_but i', this ).hasClass( "icon-double-angle-up" );

            if ( classTst_down ) {
                console.log('remove down');
                $(this ).removeClass('icon-double-angle-down');
                console.log('removed');
                $(this ).addClass('icon-double-angle-up');
                console.log('added');
            }
            if ( classTst_up ){
                console.log('remove up');
                $(this ).addClass('icon-double-angle-down');
                $(this ).removeClass('icon-double-angle-up');
            }
        });

   });
```

Comment: `$(this).removeClass('icon-double-angle-down');`

Comment: Sorry Matt, but no it does not work., I will try and inclide a snip of code

Comment: What is `this`? table, a div???? Show your HTML and code where are you using these statement

Comment: Show us the rest of your code .... how do we know what `this` is? **You know, we don't**

Comment: What did you think `this` is in your example? How did you think it would refer to a single row? You are running this is a doc ready handler. How's it supposed to know which row you are referring to?

Comment: This may be quite helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean; at the first use of `this`, use `console.log( this )` to see that `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: what's `.header`? Post a fiddle (or a stack snippet) so people can actually see what you are doing. In your case `this` will be the element with the `header` class that was clicked. Also, you don't need the `$function()` part. That makes no sense.

Comment: What is the user supposed to be clicking on? The span? The `.collapse` div?

Comment: Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/7h1gn4cx/

Comment: Why would you just randomly put `this` there and assume it would work??? If I want to target the next row do I put `next`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you understand is that you don't actually want to bind event handler to `.header` container, but rather to individual `.Collapse` items. if so you can then dramatically simplify your code if you use `toggleClass`:

```
$('.notificationDetail').on('click', '.Collapse', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.rowHead_but i', this).toggleClass('icon-double-angle-down icon-double-angle-up');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7h1gn4cx/

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complicated. Why do you need two classes? - try something like:

```
$('.notificationDetail .header').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this).find('.rowHead_but i');
    $el.toggleClass('icon-double-angle-down');
});
```