# Hapi showing undefined variable inside handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm using Hapi.js for a project and a config variable that I'm passing to my handler is coming up as *undefined* when I call my route. What am I doing wrong?

**server.js**

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 8080);

// passing this all the way to the handler
var config = {'number': 1};

var routes = require('./routes')(config);
server.route(routes);

server.start();
```

**routes.js**

```
var Home = require('../controllers/home');

module.exports = function(config) {
    var home = new Home(config);
    var routes = [{
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: home.index
    }];
    return routes;
}
```

**controllers/home.js**

```
var Home = function(config) {
    this.config = config;
}

Home.prototype.index = function(request, reply) {

    // localhost:8080
    // I expected this to output {'number':1} but it shows undefined
    console.log(this.config); 

    reply();
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the ownership of `this`. The value of `this` within any given function call is determined by how the function is called not where the function is defined. In your case above `this` was referring to the global `this` object.

You can read more on that here: [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

In short the solution to the problem is to change routes.js to the following:

```
var Home = require('../controllers/home');

module.exports = function(config) {
    var home = new Home(config);
    var routes = [{
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function(request, reply){
            home.index(request, reply);
        }
    }];
    return routes;
}
```

I've tested this and it works as expected. On a side note, you're missing out on a lot of hapi functionality by structuring your code in this way, I generally use plugins to register routes instead of requiring all routes as modules and using `server.route()`.

See this project, feel free to open an issue if you have further questions on this: https://github.com/johnbrett/hapi-level-sample

Comment: Thanks for the answer John! this makes sense. I'm loading my handlers dynamically, I trimmed down the code just for this example. Could I have used the internals variable inside the home controller to hold my config variable?

I'd really like to learn how to use Hapi properly but I haven't come across a kitchen sink type project that showcases Hapi's best practices. Are there more projects similarly to yours that I should look at?

Comment: There's a few: 
https://github.com/smaxwellstewart/hapi-dash
https://github.com/jedireza/frame
https://github.com/poeticninja/hapi-ninja
And a more complicated version where you use the Hapi CLI to install:
https://github.com/hueniverse/postmile