# Inversify instance is not injected properly

Tags: typescript, hapi, inversifyjs

I'm using inversify in a hapijs v20 and typescript.

When I try to bind a dependency in a class that will handle requests like this:

```
import * as Hapi from '@hapi/hapi'
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import { types } from "../types";

@injectable()
export default class SomeController implements SomeInterface {
    private dep: any

    public constructor(@inject(types.SomeDependecy) dep: SomeDependecy) {
        this.dep = dep
    }

    public validate(request: Hapi.Request, reply: Hapi.ResponseToolkit): Hapi.ResponseObject {

        const result = this.dep.validate(request) // The headache line

        return reply.response(result)
    }
    
}
```

and then inject use this class to register a route like this:

```
public constructor(@inject(types.SomeController) controller: SomeController) {
        this.controller = controller
    }

    public async register(server: Server) {
        await server.route([
            {
                method: 'POST',
                path: '/validate',
                handler: this.controller.validate
            }
        ])
    }
```

Everything loads up fine, and instances appear to be created. However when I hit the endpoint I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dep' of undefined
```

Thrown from the line commented in the controller as the headache line :C

Do you guys know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer in this question:

[Hapi showing undefined variable inside handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686857/hapi-showing-undefined-variable-inside-handler)

and changed the registration to this:

```
await server.route([
            {
                method: 'POST',
                path: '/validate',
                handler: (request, reply) => {
                   return this.controller.validate(request, reply)
                }
            }
        ])
```