# Javascript: Is the "this" useful or necessary in the case?

Tags: javascript

Reviewing some legacy code and saw it. The function body was done in pure Javascript without using any 3rd party library.

Could anyone shed a light on the use of "*this*" in `(function() { })(this)`?

Full codes:

```
(function() {
var root = this;
var SOMEVAR;
SOMEVAR = root.SOMEVAR = {};

SOMEVAR.windowOffset = 0;
SOMEVAR.defaultBase = 195;

SOMEVAR.resizeIFrame = function(){
  // some codes     
};

SOMEVAR.resetIFrameSize = function(height) {
  // some codes
}   

window.SOMEVAR = SOMEVAR;
})(this);
```

I actually read all "this" related usages before I asked the question. I just couldn't find this usage fits in those I read. And somehow, I don't think the "this" here is not even necessary because all the codes want is to create the "SOMEVAR" and bind it to "window". Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: `this` means anything you want it to or everything by default.

Comment: It seems to be a IIFE http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression given access to the outer object not using it directly but maybe through arguments?

Comment: for functional JS programmers it's the un-named yet still-passed argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat weird example of an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). The first part:

```
(function(){})
```

simply defines a function (the outer parentheses are unnecessary). This function is then called, passing `this` as an argument. Usually one would actually declare a parameter and then do something to the parameter inside the function:

```
(function(context) {
    // do something to or with context
})(this);
```

What object is actually referenced by `this` depends on where this code is executing and whether strict mode is in effect. See [the docs for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more information.

Comment: The full codes are: 
(function() {
  var root = this;
  var SOMEVAR;
  SOMEVAR = root.SOMEVAR = {};
  
  SOMEVAR.windowOffset = 0;
  SOMEVAR.defaultBase = 195;

  SOMEVAR.resizeIFrame = function(){
    // some codes  
  };

  SOMEVAR.resetIFrameSize = function(height) {
 // some codes
  } 
  
  window.SOMEVAR = SOMEVAR;
})(this);

What confused me is the "this" here doesn't seem like useful. Is it?

Comment: @Justin_J - No, it doesn't seem useful. As I said, this is a weird example. It would at least make some sense if it were written `(function(root) { var SOMEVAR; ... })(this);`. Then `root` would be bound to whatever `this` referred to in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining an anonymous function and then immediately invoking it with the `this` parameter.

If you're just looking to understand the meaning of `this`, then refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean) other question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, what is `this`. The oldest question in the javascript book. Generally speaking, `this` refers to the context that the current code is being executed in. If you have "top level" code being run straight in a script tag, it refers to `window`. In a click event? The current element. In a constructor? The object that will be constructed. You can even make it whatever you want with call and apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this construct:

```
(function(ns) { })(this);
```

not inside other function then `this` is a reference of default namespace of script execution. In browsers that default namespace has quite strange name `window` therefore the following will output `true`:

```
(function(ns) {
  console.log( ns === window );
 })(this);
```

Such ns (namespace) variable is useful when you need for example check variable existence in namespace.  This, for example:

```
  alert(foo);
```

will rise an error "undefined variable foo", but this:

```
(function(ns) {
  alert(ns.foo);
 })(this);
```

will show alert with the word "undefined".

Another usage is in modules that can work as inside browser as in node.js and the like. Node.js has no notion of `window` so that construct above is the only reliable way to get reference to default namespace/scope object.