# in reactjs source code,what is 'this' mean in module.exports

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I read the code of https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/grunt/tasks/browserify.js

What is 'this' mean in the line 7? Can anyone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Comment: Read an introductory JavaScript guide.

Comment: No need to downvote a question, just because the author does not have js experience.

Comment: I just ask the 'this' in grunt scope,not the original 'this' mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's passing scope of grunt
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a2862f3c2f698af2007432476092b8dba8c8b534/Gruntfile.js#L57

here your can read documentation about using multitask
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask