# angular "controller as syntax" "this" data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

I dont understand what I am missing

I dont get result on html i think this problem managing with `controllerAs` syntax

**note**: I can see the result in console `console.log(this.movie);`  - its from controller

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mfApp',['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/:detail',{
            templateUrl: 'template/detail.html',
            controller : 'detailCtrl' ,
            controllerAs: 'movieAs'
    }).otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

**controller.js**

```
var mfControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);


mfControllers.controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'appServices',  function($scope, $routeParams, appServices){
    this.movie = [];
    this.id = $routeParams.detail;
    appServices.homeSearch(this.id).success(function(response){
        this.movie = response;
        console.log(this.movie);  
        // Yes, I do get array result in console
    });

}]);
```

**html**  - template/detail.html

My try

```
{{movieAs.Title}} 
{{movieAs.movie.Title}} 
{{movie.movieAs.Title}}  
{{movie.Title}} {{title}}
```

Comment: var vm = this; vm.movie= [] this  inside homeSearch is not the same of controller contest

Comment: `movieAs.movie` would work if you would change _this.movie_ instead reassign it here _this.movie = response;_

Comment: Understood , May i ask why 'this' moving to variable - variable is a just name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mfControllers.controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'appServices',  function($scope, $routeParams, appServices){
    var me = this;
    me.movie = [];
    me.id = $routeParams.detail;
    appServices.homeSearch(me.id).success(function(response){
        me.movie = response;
        console.log(me.movie);  
        // Yes, I do get array result in console
    });
}]);
```

**EDIT**

In Javascript functions are stored as objects, so from your callbeck method inside succeess, you call `this` which refers to the method that you are running and not to the controller scope.

It is best practice to store the reference to the controller in a variable which can be accessed by the callback methods. `me` is quite an arbitrary name but widely used to refer as the `parent caller`. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Understood , May i ask why 'this' moving to variable - variable is a just name

Comment: @ShibinRagh, `this` depends on how function was called, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Comment: one more question please - Is it good way that we are changing 'var vm = this'  each controller at the top of the 'controller script'

Comment: Yes do that, it is good practice. only work with vm instead of this.

Comment: A good recommendation is to use the vm syntax, as the guide says https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to wrong `this` reference.

```js
var mfControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

mfControllers
  .controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'appServices', function($scope, $routeParams, appServices) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.movie = [];
    vm.id = $routeParams.detail;
    appServices
      .homeSearch(vm.id)
      .success(function(response) {
        // vm !== this; here
        vm.movie = response;
        console.log(vm.movie);  
    });
  }]);
```

A good practice when using `controllerAs` syntax is to assign `this` to `vm` at the very beginning of a controller. It holds the reference of the controller correctly.

That is necessary because of javascript function scoping. It will be long to explain it here, but the gist of it is that *`function` creates a new scope, `this` inside a `function` will be different*. Todd Mott has a very [great write up](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) on this.

Comment: one more question please - Is it good way that we are changing 'var vm = this' each controller at the top of the 'controller script'

Comment: @ShibinRagh yes. It serves two purposes: 1) it solves the `this` problem, 2) it is very clear that `vm` refers to the controller. By the way, `vm` means "View Model", which is what controllers really meant to be