# Basic query on passing this to a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand JavaScript this better.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
// normal function call
foo(); // `this` will refer to `window`
```

When I try to pass this to a function it throws an error.

```
function foo(this) {
    console.log(this);
}
foo(); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this(…) on chrome console.
```

When I try to pass a variable that points to window I get undefined.

```
var that = this;

function foo(that) {
    console.log(that):
}
foo(); // undefined chrome console.
```

I was expecting window object in last example as when I type that on console I get window object.

```
>>> that
window....
```

Comment: `foo();` is basically the same as `foo(undefined);`. That's why `that` is `undefined`.

Comment: Either do not pass `that` so that you will get `global that` or pass `that`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` context in JavaScript depends on how the function is being called. See [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean).

1. *`this` will refer to `window`*

   ```
   function foo() {
       console.log(this);
   }
   foo();
   ```

   Here, `foo` is globally defined function and the call to `foo()` is like `window.foo()`, Thus `this` inside `foo()` refers to the `window` object.
2. *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this(…) on chrome console.*

   ```
   function foo(this) {
       console.log(this);
   }
   foo();
   ```

   `this` is reserved keyword and cannot be used as identifier name. Also note that no parameter is passed to `foo()` when invoking the function.
3. *`undefined` is logged in below code*

   ```
   var that = this; // Global that

   function foo(that) { // Parameter `that`
       console.log(that); // <-- Use semicolon here
   }
   foo(); // `that` is not passed.
   ```

   because `that` passed as parameter overshadows the global `that`. And as nothing is passed to `foo()`, `undefined` is logged.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var that = this;
 function foo(that){
   console.log(that):
 }
 foo();
```

`foo()` parameter is missing.

so `function foo(that)` will be `undefined`.

To make it work

```
 foo(that)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(this) {
    console.log(this);
}
foo(); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this(…) on chrome console.
```

**In this case, the value of this is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.**

```
function foo(this) {
    console.log(this);
}
foo(); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this(…) on chrome console.
```

**In this case, define a foo function with parameters and then call this without any value.
Inside the function, the value of this is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.**

```
var that = this;
function foo(that){
    console.log(that); //<-here is semicolon ';'
}
foo();  // undefined chrome console.
```

If you understand  two cases mentioned above may understand what happens here. For more information Please take a look: [mdn-js-this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

**this** refers to the current context of execution in Javascript. This context is something that Javascript keeps to itself and it is readonly. You can only read the variables available in that context. You cannot override it.
When you do something like this:

```
function foo(this){
    console.log(this);
}
foo();
```

with the parameter **this** in the function, you are trying to overwrite the current context which is not allowed and hence you get the error.

And, when you run this code:

```
var that = this;
function foo(that){
    console.log(that):
}
foo();
```

you are not passing any parameter while calling the foo function and hence the value of **that** is undefined. Note that the earlier assignment of **this** to **that** is overwritten in this foo function context.

Refer [this link](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) and [this](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) to know more about execution context.