# Javascript function callback variable scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am trying to pass an object variable to a callback

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var asset_update = function (connection, addr) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.addr = addr;
    this.addr_long = parseInt(addr, 16);
}

asset_update.prototype.getFromMac = function () {
    var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(this.connection);
    ps.input('addr', sql.Binary);
    ps.prepare('SELECT asset_id FROM asset_addr WHERE addr = @addr', function (err) {
        ps.execute({ addr: this.addr_long }, function (err, recordset) {
            ps.unprepare();
            console.log(recordset.length);
            console.log(this.addr_long);
        })
    });
}
```

How can I pass this.addr_long to the ps.execute() callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an arrow function to preserve this :

```
ps.prepare('SELECT asset_id FROM asset_addr WHERE addr = @addr', (err) => {
    ps.execute({ mac: this.addr_long }, function (err, recordset) { //this has been preserved
        ps.unprepare();
        console.log(recordset.length);
        console.log(this.addr_long);
    })
});
```

[Check out this doc for the ES5 alternatives](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis), which you shouldn't use anymore.

A popular one would be to rename `this` to `that` or `self`. But this is now obsolete. It would look like :

```
var self = this;
ps.prepare('SELECT asset_id FROM asset_addr WHERE addr = @addr', function (err) {
        ps.execute({ mac: self.addr_long }, function (err, recordset) {
            ps.unprepare();
            console.log(recordset.length);
            console.log(that.addr_long);
        })
    });
```

As you're new to node/JS, I suggest you read the following resources :

[What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

[Callbacks overview and tricks](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: Thank you... I am going to use lambda as it is more familiar to me, too

Answer (score -1):

```
asset_update.prototype.getFromMac = function () {
    var that = this;
    var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(this.connection);
    ps.input('addr', sql.Binary);
    ps.prepare('SELECT asset_id FROM asset_addr WHERE addr = @addr', function (err) {
        ps.execute({ mac: that.addr_long }, function (err, recordset) {
            ps.unprepare();
            console.log(recordset.length);
            console.log(that.addr_long);
        })
    });
}
```