# Not able to use $(this) inside if statement

Tags: jquery

How can I refer `$('nav > .smart-nav > li')` with `$(this)` inside if statement, instead of `$('.nav-second')`?

This is the code-

```js
if ($('nav > .smart-nav > li').is('.active')) {
  $('.nav-second').addClass('in');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav smart-nav">
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Administrator Portal</span><span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </span>
      </a>
      <ul id="" class="nav nav-second collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a href="administrator-portal.html">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="activity.html">Customer Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
        <i class="fa fa-support"></i><span>Support</span><span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </span>
      </a>
      <ul id="" class="nav nav-second collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a href="tableStyles.html">Logs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show HTML structure, How `.nav-second` is related to `nav > .smart-nav > li`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Comment: `$(this)` refers to context which context are you referring to here?

Comment: $('nav > .smart-nav > li').is('.active') returns a Boolean value.

Comment: yes I know, I want to refer on the context of `$('nav > .smart-nav > li')`

Comment: Check my last edit, form html structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
$('.smart-nav > li.active').children('ul.nav-second').addClass('in');
```

Example:-

```js
$('.smart-nav > li.active').children('ul.nav-second').addClass('in');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav smart-nav">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Administrator Portal</span><span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </span>
            </a>
            <ul id="" class="nav nav-second collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="administrator-portal.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="activity.html">Customer Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                <i class="fa fa-support"></i><span>Support</span><span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </span>
            </a>
            <ul id="" class="nav nav-second collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="tableStyles.html">Logs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Satpal changed based on html shown by OP right now

Comment: This would be the best way to add a class - but not sure if there is any other code meant to go inside the `if` (which was why I left it in my answer). Plus one anyway :)

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I have two options to use now. I marked another answer as correct before. I just can give a thumbs up for this one!

Comment: @LXhelili mark this one as the answer  - it would be the better way to do it if you don't need the `if` to do other stuff

Answer (score 2):

`$('nav > .smart-nav > li').is('.active')` is checking if any of those li that has the class active, instead if you want the li with the active class, I would do something like this:

```js
var li = $('nav > .smart-nav > li.active'); // get the active li

if(li.length){  // check if there are any
  li.find('.nav-second').addClass('in'); // here the li var acts like your this as it is the ones with the active class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't. $(this) is available only in events on elements and callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `if()` at all if you are looking for a descendant of the active `<li>` ...just combine selectors:

```
$('nav > .smart-nav > li.active .nav-second').addClass('in');
```