# how to pass this from onclick event to multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying passing "this" from onclick event to a function and than to pass this to another function, its working on the first function, but "this" not passed to the next function called from the first function ?

this is my code, please advice ?

```js
function hideProcessing(nextThis) {
  nextThis.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  nextThis.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}

function showProcessing(param) {
  param.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
  param.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  var thisElement = this

  setTimeout('hideProcessing(thisElement)', 3000);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="overlap">show me</span>
  <div id="sendContainer" class="sendContainer">
    <button onclick="showProcessing(this);">send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: u have the this stored in param. you made a mistake assigning thisElement = this. also you should not call setTimeout with string, there should be a function as first parameter. in that function you will still have access to 'param' which is your this.

Comment: try this.name or id like that . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should correct that 'this' in your onclick function to param
Secondly call your setTimeout function as following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  hideProcessing(thisElement)
}, 3000);
```

setTimeout function takes a function as an input not a string

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/wopeyosovu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a timeout with a wrapper function, also `this`, in the scope of the function, is the window.

Try:

```
function hideProcessing(nextThis) {
    nextThis.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
    nextThis.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}

function showProcessing(param) {
    param.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
    param.parentNode.style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(function(){//wrapper anonymous function
        hideProcessing(param);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (pun intended) to understand a little more about scope and how and when use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hideProcessing(nextThis){
console.log('nextThis', nextThis);
nextThis.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
nextThis.parentNode.style.display = "block";

}
 
function showProcessing(param){
param.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
param.parentNode.style.display = "none";

setTimeout(hideProcessing(param), 3000);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="overlap">show me</span>
    <div id="sendContainer" class="sendContainer"> 
      <button onclick="showProcessing(this);" >send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```