# can someone please explain how this jquery code works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i picked this code online but i'm unable to understand how it works. without understanding i cannot edit it for my use. it is for closing a panel by up-slide when i click on "x" button. i want to know how is the effect created in the script?
here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Using Slide Up</h3>
            <span class="pull-right clickable" data-effect="slideUp">x</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the script working on this is:

```
    $(function() {
        $('.clickable').on('click', function() {
            var effect = $(this).data('effect');
            $(this).closest('.panel')[effect]();
        });
    });
```

Comment: What part of the code exactly are you not understanding? Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: When clicking on `.clickable` element, it applies `slideUp` to the closest `.panel` item

Comment: is this `$(this).closest('.panel')[effect]()` the line you don't get?

Comment: @Bergi yes i'm familiar with jquery.  please explain these two lines specifically: var effect = $(this).data('effect');
            $(this).closest('.panel')[effect]();

Comment: You are obviously not familiar with jQuery if you don't understand those two basic lines. All the information you need is in their documentation about this.  I suggest you go read them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean

Comment: @JohnSmith i'm familiar with "this" .the link is not helpful

Comment: @Gurjotkaur Which things do http://api.jquery.com/data/, http://api.jquery.com/closest/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation not explain?

Comment: @Gurjotkaur if you are, then there's nothing to explain

Comment: And some of you need to read http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6565/how-to-politely-handle-support-requests-which-lack-some-basic-understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.clickable')
```

This is your jquery selector. It grabs all elements with the class "clickable" (the dot represents class. if it had been "#clickable" it would look for any element with the id of clickable)

```
.on('click', function() {
}
```

Now for all your selected elements, we're wiring up a click event. When the element selected is clicked, then the function will run.

```
var effect = $(this).data('effect');
```

In this line, we're setting the variable "effect" to have the value of the data property "data-effect" from the clicked element (which can be referenced in the function using the keyword "this"). The ".data" method returns all properties that are prefixed "data-".

```
$(this).closest('.panel')[effect]();
```

Here we're now searching for the closest element with the class "panel" to our clicked element (which, remember, can be referenced in the function using "this").

As "effect" is a variable, the code

```
.[effect]()
```

is identical (in your example) to coding (as your data-effect="slideUp" in the html)

```
.slideUp()
```

In JavaScript, you can use either dot notation or bracket notation interchangeably.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. This is the jQuery code. There is a `click` event bound to all elements with class `clickable`:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {...});
```

Then you want to know what effect you would like to have. To do so, you take the `data-effect` attribute value:

```
var effect = $(this).data('effect'); // returns 'slideUp'
```

At the end, you want to slide up the closest element with class `panel` attached to it:

```
$(this).closest('.panel')[effect]();
```

I understand that this part may be kind of hard to understand. The trick here is that you keep the effect name in a variable. And want to call the method with that name on the `.panel` element. This is how you do it in JS- you put the variable in square brackets and append parentheses. This way you call the `.slideUp()` method. It is evaluated to something like this:

```
$(this).closest('.panel').slideUp();
```

Also, I suggest you read something about jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/