# accessing newquestion variable further down in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got this Vue.js code below which has a variable `newQuestion` which I send to the function get answer like so `this.getAnswer(newQuestion)` where further along down in the methods as this line `getAnswer: _.debounce(` I would like to access it so I can insert it here `axios.post('http://35.196.91.194/insurance-list', {})` as part of the values sent in the post.

The full code below

```
var InsuranceVM = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#insurance-form',
  data: {
    insurance_types: [],
        insurance_type: '',
    insurance_types_get_error: '',
  },
  watch: {
        // whenever question changes, this function will run
        insurance_type: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
              //this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'

          this.getAnswer(newQuestion)
        }
      },
      methods: {
        getAnswer: _.debounce(
          function () {  
            var vm = this;
            axios.post('http://35.196.91.194/insurance-list', {})
              .then(function (response) {
                vm.insurance_types_get_error = '';

                vm.insurance_types = response.data.results;

              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                vm.insurance_types_get_error = 'Error! Could not reach the API. ' + error;
              })
          },
          500
        )
      }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean

Comment: I don't think I can use `this.newQuestion`

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to have added is newQuestion to the function like so

```
getAnswer: _.debounce(
      function (newQuestion) {
```

so I could use it there after.