# What is happening in the creation and execution phase of an object?

Tags: javascript

I created a normal JavaScript object, like this:

```js
let obj = {
    name : "something",
    print() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
    
let res = obj.print()
console.log(res);
```

In this example `obj` has a name and a simple method. I am calling the method from the outside. After that I log the return value to the console, which is **undefined**.

I don't understand what is happening behind the scenes within the object. Please explain to me the creation and execution phase for this code.

Comment: `print` doesn't return anything, it just logs something by itself.

Comment: I can understand, but my question is how javascript behind the scene is working.

Comment: for example:::/*
// creational phase

obj = undefind
res = undefind

execution phase
name = ref
print = ref


*/

Comment: What are "*creational and execution phase*"???

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, the JavaScript interpreter creates an object in memory and refers to it through `obj`. When you call `obj.print()`, it refers to the same object and calls the method defined.

In the method, [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean) refers to the object itself (`obj`), and is set by the JS interpreter as an implicit reference.

At last, you forgot to return the value from `print()`. So, nothing is assigned to `res`. Refer to the following example, as it prints the value of `res` correctly, when a value is returned from the function.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "something",
  print() {
    console.log(this.name);
    return this.name;
  }
}

let res = obj.print()
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write about the "behind the scenes" that you are asking for. Unfortunately this might confuse you, instead of making things clearer as JavaScript is quite a "different" language on its own.

In JavaScript a function is an object. Sometimes even called a first-class object. It has everything an object has (attributes and methods) and in addition can further more be invoked. Don't believe me? See for yourself:

```js
function abracadabra()
{
  return "this is magic";
}

console.log(abracadabra.name);
console.log(abracadabra.call());
```

Now a method is simply another function to which an attribute of an object is referring to. Let's take your example:

```
let obj = {
    name : "something",
    print() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

Here `obj` is defined as an object with two attributes. A value type and a function. When you call the `obj.print()` function the following happens:

- The function is called.
- The so-called function context `this` is set to the object that the method is called upon. You can use `this` to access other attributes of the same object.

What exactly is `this`? As said it is the so-called function context that can refer to four different objects depending on how a function is called.

1. The function is called as a function. e.g. `abracadabra()` => `this` is referring to the global context, to which it is always referring by default.

The global context is dependent on the environment JavaScript is executed in. Remember JavaScript can not only run in a browser. It can also be used as a server-side scripting language. In the browser the global context is the current browser window. Don't believe me? See for yourself:

```js
// We are not in any method, still "this" is available:
console.log(this.toString());
```

2. The function is called as a method. e.g. `obj.print()` => `this` is referring to the object the method is invoked on. I described this above.
3. The function is called as a constructor. e.g. `new abracadabra()` =>  A new empty object is created and `this` is referring to it. Now the function should extend the empty object with attributes.
4. The function is called using its `apply` or `call` methods => `this` is referring to whatever you pass as the very first argument of these methods.

So to sum it up: It can get tricky to really understand how these things work in JavaScript. This is because basically there are only objects and functions in the language. Methods look like methods, but are in reality only functions as well.

To get a really good in depth understanding I can recommend the book [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](https://www.manning.com/books/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja).