# Is this a right way to set variables as private

Tags: javascript

Is this a right way to set a variables as private?

```
function test(a, b){
        let aa = a
        let bb = b
        return {
            getA: () => {
                return aa
            },
            getB: () => {
                return bb
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I can't access `aa` and `bb`  directrly. And if I put `this` keyword infront of the variables, will it be accepted as an object? I know that in JavaScript functions are objects but it become more like object syntax. I am confused a lot from all the JavaScript options. It seems like there is no conventions in anything.
The `this` type:

```
function test(a, b){
        this.aa = a
        this.bb = b
        return {
            getA: () => {
                return this.aa
            },
            getB: () => {
                return this.bb
            }
        }
    }
```

Both examples seems equal to me. The summed question - Is the privace of those variables is achieved in those ways ?

Comment: Have a read up on JS deign patterns, it seems your trying to create a [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), but there are other options.

Comment: Will take an I on it for sure. In fact, I am trying to understand which are the right ways at all in JS. I know for different situations different solution can be used. Just trying to sum up the things a little.

Comment: Be careful of "right way". Typically there is no right way, just different ways.

Comment: @Liam Yes yes. Just sayed like this. Understand that :) It is like there is so many ways that I can do the things here.

Comment: Is it problem? You mean it has to be like that `this.getA`  right ? Or it is like a convention ? Like the constructor functions have to start with capital letter lets say.

Comment: The second block is not private. `aa` is scoped to the `window` object

Comment: @CertainPerformance the second one is not private. And if the function is called without `new` the variables/properties are not just public but global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These blocks of code are not equal. See below:

```js
function test(a, b){
        let aa = a
        let bb = b
        return {
            getA: () => {
                return aa
            },
            getB: () => {
                return bb
            }
        }
    }
    
let testResult = test(1, 2);
console.log(testResult.aa)
//error
console.log(aa);
```

vs

```js
function test(a, b){
        //this here === window
        this.aa = a
        this.bb = b
        return {
            getA: () => {
                return this.aa
            },
            getB: () => {
                return this.bb
            }
        }
    }
    
let testResult = test(1,2);
console.log(testResult.aa);
//can get aa
console.log(aa);
```

`this` in your second block of code is the `window` object. So `aa` is not private. Where as in the first block, it's block scoped and not accessible. So `aa` is only "private" in the first one.

> Is this the "right" way?

As I [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556637/is-this-a-right-way-to-set-variables-as-private/53556726#comment93978611_53556637) this is just a [design pattern (revealing module pattern)](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). Be wary of "right" way. "right" is subjective and depends on context. There is no "right" way, but this is a common way of structuring this kind of thing.

This is just using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to scope a variable. There is no "private" declaration, as such, in js. Just scoped variables.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. If declare variabl `let myVar = new test(1,2)` than this will point to the `myVar`. So from what I understand `this` shouldn't be used in functions ( which are not made to be constructors ). Am I on the right way ? :)

Comment: @Tnc Andrei No no. Just testing. Wont use anything that I do not understand :)

Comment: `this` can be used @TomaTomov , but you need to be aware as to what [`this` actually means in the scope that your using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean).

Comment: Get it! Thank you very much!

Comment: The second example should be called like this: `let testResult = new test(1,2);`. Calling test with the new keyword will return an object and everything attached to `this` will belong to test instead of window