# What is the use of the “this” keyword here?

Tags: javascript, class

```js
class Rabbit1 {
  constructor(name, color, type) {
    if (arguments.length !== 3) throw new Error("Wrong length of arguments given");
    this.ar1 = name;
    this.ar2 = color;
    this.ar3 = type;
    this.testExtra = [];
    if (!name) {
      this.testExtra[0] = "This is in the constructor";
    } else {
      this.testExtra[0] = "Name is True";
    }
  }
  speak(line) {
    console.log(`The ${this.ar2} Rabbit, called '${this.ar1}'  and says it\ 's a ${this.ar3} rabbit, Oh and it\'s saying ${line} too... ${this.testExtra}`);
  }
  speak2(speak) {
    console.log("Hello " + this.ar1);
  }
}

let blackR = new Rabbit1(false, "black", "gentle");

blackR.speak("Hello");
```

I’m asking this question because, if you take a look at

```
if (!name)
```

The binding `name` is used, and it refers to the `name` of the instance of the class (in this case `blackR`).

So why do you we use `this.name` when `name` on its own refers to the `name` value given in the instance of the class.

Please bear, with the poor indentation.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Comment: You can use `this.ar1` or `name` in the constructor, because there (and only there) both exist. `name` is just the function's parameter (a local variable), while `this.ar1` has just been defined with the same value, and is a member of the object instance.

Comment: "So why do you we use this.name when name on its own refers to the name value given in the instance of the class." -> `name` does refer to the name (huh), but it won't exist anymore at the end of the constructor's code. `this.name`, on the other hand, will remain within the returned object.

Comment: They are not the same binding. name by itself is the parameter of the constructor. They just happen to have the same value. Actually you should not make references to parameters because you risk capturing them and it could cause some weird effects unless you specifically intend to capture them.

Comment: check this for typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Comment: @Jeto This answered the question, what I really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The binding `name` is used, and it refers to the `name` of the instance of the class (in this case `blackR`).

No, it doesn't. *name* is the first parameter in the constructor:

```
constructor(name, color, type) {
```

The first value in the call is `false`:

```
let blackR = new Rabbit1(false, "black", "gentle");
```

So that is the value assigned to *name*. It's also assigned to *this.ar1* in:

```
this.ar1 = name;
```

The code produces:

```
"The black Rabbit, called 'false'  and says..."
```

Which shows that *this.ar1* has a value of *false*.

> So why do you we use `this.name` when `name` on its own refers to the name value

The expression *this.name* does not appear in the OP. If you meant "Why is this.ar1 used instead of name", it's impossible to tell from the posted code. Within the constructor, they are essentially identical and have the same value.

However, *ar1* is a public property of the instance, so can be changed later.