# Jquery UI Autocomplete Extra Parameters and Autofill - A frustrated solution

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Been looking into Jquery UI's Autocomplete (v1.8.5) and realized there is a sever lack of documentation on sending extra parameters and shooting extra data to autofill other fields. What I have works, but seriously, seems like such a hack... Any thoughts on how to improve this?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var optofirst = {

            width: 375,

            // doing "$(this)" here fails

            source: function( request, response ) {

            // grab the calling element
            // "$(this)" here works but ya gotta dig to get to the ID

            var cat = $(this);
            var callid = cat[0].element.context.id; //digging away

            $.ajax({

                // doing "$(this)" here fails

                url: "automagic.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                term : request.term,

                //send its ID to the php script
                grab : callid,
            },

            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {

                // start assigning item handles to the response

                label: item.first,
                value: item.first,
                last: item.last,
                }
                }));
            }
            });
        },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.last :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

                // make #lname have the value last name
                // the "item" in this case appears to get its info from the handles assign in "success:"

                $("#flyover #lname").attr("value",ui.item.last);
            },
        minLength: 2,
        };

        $("#flyover #fname").autocomplete(optofirst);

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea looks good to me.  Your code is pretty close to [jQueryUI's custom data and display demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data).

There are a few things you could improve on though:

1. `// doing "$(this)" here fails` both inside the options object for autocomplete and your AJAX call, because `this` in JavaScript does not make sense in object literals; it contains the context of a function call (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) for a great explanation of `this`);
2. Inside the `source` function, `this` works because now there's a function around it.  `this` has a context.
3. Instead of:

   ```
   var callid = cat[0].element.context.id; //digging away
   ```

   You could write:

   ```
   var calid = this.element.attr('id');
   ```

   This is because `this` in this case is already a jQuery object.  `$(this)` is redundant.  Also, the `element` property is also a jQuery object, so you can just access the `id` using `attr()`

The rest looks ok to me.  Have a look at the demo I referenced--it does some similar things to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That was actually really helpful. Didn't even think about how when I include "this" inside the curly braces for the ajax call, I'm saying that in the object literal not the function call. Much appreciated! Your "this.element.attr('id');" worked well too! You rock!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the source property. Set a function instead of an url.
You should need only to edit url and replace customData line for as many custom properties you want to send to the server.
For example:

```
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'data.php',
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    customData : $('#something').val()
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                  }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3}, {

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to do this in rails 3.1 using coffeescript
Heres a [gist for it on github](https://gist.github.com/1870941)