# Javascript Variable Explanation

Tags: javascript

very simple question...

would like to know what the

"this" variable represents in javascript...
thanks

Comment: Take it from the creator, Brendan Eich himself; http://www.aminutewithbrendan.com/pages/20110303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [explanation on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) might be a good start.

There is also a [nice answer by Alan Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149) here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely speaking, it represents what is to the left of the dot when you invoke the function:

```
// inside of f, this = x
x.f(1, 2, 3)

// inside of f, this = c 
a.b.c.f(1, 2, 3)
```

There are a number of exceptions to the rule.

First, if you have no dot:

```
// inside of f, this = the global object ("window", if you're in a browser environment)
f(1, 2, 3)
```

Secondly, you can use the methods `call` and/or `apply` to explicitly set the value of `this`:

```
// Invokes f with this = myVar, not x (arguments 2 an onward are the ordinary arguments)
x.f.call(myVar, 1, 2, 3)

// Invokes f with this = myVar, not x (arguments are passed as an array)
x.f.apply(myVar, [1, 2, 3])
```

Third, when you invoke a function using `new`, `this` will refer to the newly created object:

```
// inside of f, this = a new object, not x
new x.f(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable in javascript, as in any other language, refers to the current object.
For example:

```
document.getElementById('link1').onclick = function()
{
 this.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

In the onclick handler the this would refer to the DOMElement which you got by id.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to the current owner of the function or scope we're in.

You can find more info here : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.
Check the below link for more explanation.
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html