# What is the "this" in an example JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Below is the entire contents of a JS/JQuery file. I didn't write it, but I'm trying to add on to it. I am having trouble understanding what `this` is referring to. I haven't seen functions set up in this style before (`SmartPhone = function() {}`)

```
SmartPhone = function()
{
    this.miniMap = new GameModeMap();

    this.init = function()
    {
        var self=this;
        var $PhoneContainer = $("#PhoneContainer");
        $PhoneContainer.append("<div id='PhoneScreen'></div>");
        $PhoneContainer.append("<div class='PhoneButton'></div>");
        $('.PhoneButton').click(function(){self.toggleClicked()});

        this.miniMap.init("#PhoneScreen");

        //append the appMenu
        $("#PhoneScreen").append("<div id='AppMenu'></div>");
        $("#AppMenu").hide();
        initMenu();
        //toggleClicked();
    }

    this.toggleClicked = function() 
    {
        console.log(this);
        $('#PhoneContainer').toggleClass ('clicked');
        $('#PhoneScreen').toggleClass ('vertical');
        this.miniMap.toggle();
        $('#AppMenu').toggle();
    }

    this.init();
}
```

Comment: You can't hide code in here, after you posted, it's forever in the edit history, I'm not sure about what license your code turns into when you post it here.

Comment: Yes, but this is better than having it flying out in the open.

Comment: I don't see why hide that. It's so trivial that anyone can reproduce that. Also, by doing that, you won't help other people that'll find this question on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using the [Object Functionality](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm) of JavaScript.

`SmartPhone` is essentially a class structure in this example, with `init()` being the construct (called by the last `this.init()` line within `SmartPhone`.

`this` is refering to the scope, and in this case the object being created.

Comment: I chose your answer because you best answered the question of what `this` was in the example method

Comment: @Briz: Another great resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149

Answer (score 2):

[How `this` works](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HAMQh/)

```
var Construct = function() {
  this.magic = 42;
}
var c = new Construct();
alert(c.magic === 42);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "this" variable in JavaScript can point to many different things depending on your context. There is a great blog post on this called: [Understanding JavaScript’s this keyword](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)

In the context you are showing, this will be bound to the object created from the SmartPhone constructor.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the SmartPhone object.  For instance, this.init is defining the init method for the SmartPhone.  Later, you could access it by using SmartPhone.init().

Comment: So, in essence I should be able to call toggleClicked with SmartPhone.toggleClicked(); ? I tried this and it does nothing.