# jquery: what does "$(this)" exactly mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a program and it works well.
See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HP8Xd/).

This is the code:

```
<div id="round"></div>

<style>
#round{
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
left: 400px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
</style>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#round").click(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#round").animate(
                {height: 250,
                width: 150,
                top:150,
                left: 425},
                {duration: 300}
                ).
            animate(
                {height: 200,
                width: 200,
                top:200,
                left: 400},
                {duration: 300}
            );
        }, 0);
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I change "#round" to "this". It won't work. why?
(actually it works, but when I put them into setInterval(), it won't work)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#round").click(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#round").animate(
                {height: 250,
                width: 150,
                top:150,
                left: 425},
                {duration: 300}
                ).
            animate(
                {height: 200,
                width: 200,
                top:200,
                left: 400},
                {duration: 300}
            );
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

change to "this", it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#round").click(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $(this).animate(
                {height: 250,
                width: 150,
                top:150,
                left: 425},
                {duration: 300}
                ).
            animate(
                {height: 200,
                width: 200,
                top:200,
                left: 400},
                {duration: 300}
            );
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: See [Javascript _this_ gotchyas](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-gotchas/)

Comment: [More than you ever wanted to know about `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149)

Comment: @andyb: Funny, was just looking for that post...

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you're calling another function (setInterval). Can you pass $this in setInterval(function($this){...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the member that invokes the current function...

then you can wrap it in the jquery function `$()` to select it just like you would another selector.

So `setInterval` calls a anonymous function so it is not invoked by a referencable member, so it defaults to the `window` object.

save the `this` context in a variable and then use it internally like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#round").click(function(){
        var clicked = this;   //<----store the click context outside setInterval
        setInterval(function(){
            $(clicked).animate(  //<----------use it here
                {height: 250,
                width: 150,
                top:150,
                left: 425},
                {duration: 300}
                ).
            animate(
                {height: 200,
                width: 200,
                top:200,
                left: 400},
                {duration: 300}
            );
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Inside of a jQuery bound event function, `this` refers to the current DOM element from the collection which is being operated on.  Since it is a DOM element, passing it to jQ like `$( this )` makes it a jQuery collection so that you can do more jQuery stuff to it.

In your modified, non-workng code, however, you moved that into a new anonymous function. Inside of *that* function, `this` now refers to the new scope.

You need to get a reference to `this` before your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#round").click(function(){
        var jQuerizedElement = $( this );
        setInterval(function(){
            jQuerizedElement.animate(
                {height: 250,
                width: 150,
                top:150,
                left: 425},
                {duration: 300}
                ).
            animate(
                {height: 200,
                width: 200,
                top:200,
                left: 400},
                {duration: 300}
            );
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that jondavidjohn and I have given the same solution, but he chose to sotre only a reference to `this` in `self` whereas I chose to store a referenced to the jQuerized `this` in `jQuerizedElement`. Either is fine in this case.

Answer (score 5):

`$(this)` is context sensitive. Each [anonymous, in this case] function you're entering, the value of `$(this)` changes. For example:

```
$('#round').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')) // alerts round
    setInterval(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id')) // alerts undefined
    });
});
```

Comment: For the record, it's not `$(this)` specifically, but `this`. `$()` is just wrapping (or attempting thereof) the reference in a jQuery object.

Comment: Good addition. That is important to note.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a callback function that is fired by setInterval on a different context...

You can handle this by copying 'this' to an other variable ex :

```
var that = this:
```

And on callback

```
$(that).animate...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is basically context related. When you say $(this) if this is a dom element it will give you jquery object associated with this dom element.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well it seems that `$(this)` is just the **node** that was **triggerd**.

For instance when you have a click **event** on a **button**. In the callback of the event you can use $(this) that represent the node of the **button**...