# jquery show and hide pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi hope someone can help me with this i want pictures to hide and show when hovering over them.... all divs have the same classes and the pictures it toggles has the same classes aswell example:

```
<div class="square"><img class = "imagesbw" src="images/image3bw.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
<img class = "imagescol" src="images/image3.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
</div>

<div class="square"><img class = "imagesbw" src="images/image3bw.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
<img class = "imagescol" src="images/image3.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
</div>

<div class="square"><img class = "imagesbw" src="images/image3bw.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
<img class = "imagescol" src="images/image3.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
</div>

<div class="square"><img class = "imagesbw" src="images/image3bw.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
<img class = "imagescol" src="images/image3.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
</div>

<div class="square"><img class = "imagesbw" src="images/image3bw.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
<img class = "imagescol" src="images/image3.png"  alt="" width="91" height="76">
</div>
```

so there a black and white picture above a color picture..i want to mousein over one of them and hid that one to show the one behind...

Heres what i did in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".imagesbw").mouseover(function(){
  $(".imagesbw").hide();



  })
    $(".imagescol").mouseout(function(){
  $(".imagesbw").show();
});
})
```

Only problem is that there are multiple of them and all of them show and hide at the same time while over one... i just want the one the mouse is over to hide and show and so on....

im new to jquery hope this make sense

[**Here's**](http://www.fullyillustrated.com/) a sample of what i want to do
under the heading LATEST RELEASES and SNEAKY PEAKS

thanks

Comment: also, as a suggestion i think you can achieve that effect using css grayscale filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute the code using `this` context, In the event handler `this` refers to element which invoked the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".imagesbw").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
    $(".imagescol").mouseout(function(){
        //Here use the prev() method in conjection with this 
        $(this).prev(".imagesbw").show(); 
    });
})
```

Comment: Yep. Check this out too if you are new to jQuery/JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749634/jquery-what-does-this-exactly-mean.

Comment: You are just very faster than me in a 30 sec gap! `:)`

Comment: with small interval of time. :p three answers

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `this` . In you method the first class will pickup every time and with `this` the current element event will occur .`this` is a reference to the member that invokes the current function

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $(".imagesbw").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).hide();



  })
    $(".imagescol").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
})
```

Comment: Just to be picky, `this` isn't an event.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a generic solution. You should be particular to use `this` this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".imagesbw").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
    $(".imagescol").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).prev(".imagesbw").show();
    });
});
```

**Update:** Just saw even [Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) has given the same answer! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide all bw images (you can also do this by css - display:none)
  $('.imagesbw').hide();

  // on mouseover event - hide current color image and show b&w image
  $(".imagescol").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $(this).prev().show();
  });

  // on mouseout event - hide current b&w image and show color image
  $(".imagesbw").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).hide();
     $(this).next().show();
  });
});
```

JSFiddle for your example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4mkhnjvm/)

You can also achieve the same effect by using css only

```
.imagescol:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Then you don't need two different images (color and b&w) and you also don't need javascripts. JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbon42vm/).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this in this scenario

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$(".imagesbw").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
})
$(".imagescol").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".imagesbw").show();
});
```

})

http://plnkr.co/edit/1vDNHnaRKkAIfxhzSr3e?p=preview