# Toggle only the content within given div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a question regarding using the toggle function after a button press. I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navigation').click(function () {                                
        $(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
    });
});
```

This works perfect together with the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      <div class="navigation">
        <span class="expand">
          expand          
        </span>
        <span class="collapse">
          collapse          
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But whenever I have this HTML format:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      <div class="navigation">
        <span class="expand">
          expand          
        </span>
        <span class="collapse">
          collapse          
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
      <div class="navigation">
        <span class="expand">
          expand          
        </span>
        <span class="collapse">
          collapse          
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The toggle is applied to both containers, which is logical but not desired. How could I trigger only the siblings of the pressed navigation button?

I tried something like:

```
$(this).next(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
```

but that does not work. Any help is appreciated!

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fre64k7d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea; you need to use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event and find it's related `.expand` and `.collapse` elements, however `next()` looks for siblings, whereas the elements you need to retrieve are children so you need to use `find()`:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navigation').click(function () {                                
        $(this).find(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fre64k7d/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast and clear answer! This really helped me. I thought I was close but your explanation makes everything clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()` like following.

```
$(this).find(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! 
find() is your friend. When coupled with $(this), it will search through child nodes that match your criteria.

```
$(function () {
            $('.navigation').click(function () {                                
                $(this).find(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
            });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaftdLfr/)

Answer (score 1):

`$(".expand, .collapse").toggle();` this would apply `toggle` to all elements with classes `expand` and `collapse` irrespective of your clicked `.navigation` div.

Change to

```
  $(this).find(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
```

You may read about `$(this)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749634/jquery-what-does-this-exactly-mean).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the container div of these classes, you can simply use `$(".expand, .collapse", $(this))`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navigation').click(function() {
    $(".expand, .collapse", $(this)).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="expand">
          expand          
        </span>
      <span class="collapse">
          collapse          
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <div class="navigation">
      <span class="expand">
          expand          
        </span>
      <span class="collapse">
          collapse          
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey tried to research on your question and got this useful link https://api.jquery.com/siblings/. You can use it as follows:

```
$(this).siblings(".expand, .collapse").toggle();
```

Comment: Note that this won't work as `siblings()` gets sibling elemens, yet `.collapse` and `.expand` are children.