# Meaning of this two jquery expression?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

HTML CODE

```
<tr class="roti">

    <td class="ts" rowspan="2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control totalSale" id="totalSaleAmountForRoti" name='totalSaleAmountForRoti' value="0" readonly>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr class="roti">
    column related class="form-control totalSale"
</tr>
```

What is the difference between them and their meaning?

```
var $class = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');
```

1)

```
totalSale = $(this).parents('.' + $class).find('.totalSale');
```

2)

```
totalSale = $(this).parents('.' + $class).siblings('.' + $class + ':last').find('.totalSale');
```

And what meanings of this below code?

```
if ($(this).parent().siblings().children().hasClass('.totalSale')) { ... }
```

Comment: [**Learn jQuery**](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: I just need to know the difference between above two code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: There is some HTML missing in your given code.
In the second `<tr>` block, HTML isn't valid.

**Second**: The short answer to your question is: **No difference**. Both statements fail.

---

Care to read?

Supposing the HTML is more like this:

```
<tr class="roti">
    <td class="ts" rowspan="2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control totalSale" id="totalSaleAmountForRoti" name='totalSaleAmountForRoti' value="0" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="roti">
    <td class="ts" rowspan="2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control totalSale" id="other_id" name='other_name' value="other_value" readonly>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then, in your code, you define the variable `$class`:

```
var $class = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');
```

Which will be set to the value of the *grand-parent's* attribute class, if found.

This variable definition call is triggered by an event handler or a function binded to an element.
I'm sure about it because of [`$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749709/2159528).

---

Let's assume it's the first `<input>`.
**So $class = "roti".**

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) is the element wrapping...
.parent().parent() is the second level of element wrapping...
And so on.
Okay?

**Then**
You have two statements here, that try to [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) an element having a class "totalSale", within the childs elements of a **collection** of elements.
   *Yeah*, this sentence needs to be read twice.

In both cases, the collection is the result of [method chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp).
And the result from it will be stored as the "totalSale" variable... if found.

**Now**, you have two elements with **class** "totalSale" in your given HTML.
So let's see the first statement:

1st:

```
totalSale = $(this).parents('.' + $class).find('.totalSale');
```

From the first `<input>`,

1. check within the parent collection if it finds an element with class = $class ("roti") ==> result is UNDEFINED.
2. Sorry, ends there.
3. It won't try to find a child element with class "totalSale" within an undefined collection.

2nd:

```
totalSale = $(this).parents('.' + $class).siblings('.' + $class + ':last').find('.totalSale');
```

From the first `<input>`,

1. check within the parent collection if it finds an element with class = $class ("roti") ==> result is UNDEFINED.
2. Sorry, ends there too.
3. It won't check if there is a [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) element with class "roti" within an "undefined" collection... And certainly not finding the [last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
4. It won't check either if it finds a child with class "totalSale".

It all stopped at #2.



You should read more on jQuery [starting here](https://learn.jquery.com/).

---

**Advise**

You should at leat know what you want to understand from a code sample that you don't fully understand.

If you don't know what you want to understand, this community won't help very much.

A MUST reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks bro. and sorry for the question lackings :(

Comment: I gave you a couple links in this answer. You should read if you want to learn. [Internet was invented](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) in the late 90's... Not so long ago. It's time to jump in. ;)