# How to fade out just one button with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I have a row of buttons:

```
 <div class="console_row1">
            <button class="button">TOFU</button>
            <button class="button">BEANS</button>
            <button class="button">RICE</button>
            <button class="button">PASTA</button>
            <button class="button">QUINOA</button>
            <button class="button">SOY MILK</button>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to make a program where if you click on one of the buttons, it ONLY fades out the button you clicked on. I have the following Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button").click(function(){
                $(".button").fadeOut()    
            });    
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)`.`this` will give the reference to the member that invokes the current function.You can [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749634/jquery-what-does-this-exactly-mean)  here

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button").click(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut()    
            });    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="console_row1">
            <button class="button">TOFU</button>
            <button class="button">BEANS</button>
            <button class="button">RICE</button>
            <button class="button">PASTA</button>
            <button class="button">QUINOA</button>
            <button class="button">SOY MILK</button>
</div>
And I'm trying to make a program where if you click on one of the buttons, it ONLY fades out the button you clicked on. I have the following Jquery:
```

For fadeout using css

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".button").click(function(){
                    $(this).addClass('fadeOut')    
                });    
            });
```

```css
.button{
  transition:all .5s linear;
}

.fadeOut{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="console_row1">
                <button class="button">TOFU</button>
                <button class="button">BEANS</button>
                <button class="button">RICE</button>
                <button class="button">PASTA</button>
                <button class="button">QUINOA</button>
                <button class="button">SOY MILK</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! It worked. Now how do I stop the other buttons from moving after one fades out?

Comment: @AhmedPanju You can achieve that simply using css insteadof fadeOut.Added a second snippet.Please check that

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot. I'm still starting out and stuff haha