# what does 'this' represent inside ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, this

I have been trying to use this inside an ajax function to refer the event target . but it seems that is not the way I think.

for example:

```
$('#test').live('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:
         data:...,
         success:function(mes){
             $(this).append('mes');
         }
     });
});
```

so here $(this) does not refer to the ('#test') selector. what does it refer to??
thanks for any explanation.

Comment: [More than you ever wanted to know about `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149)

Comment: @andyb, great reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the success callback `this` refers to a global object created by jQuery containing information about the AJAX rerquest. If you want to get the original DOM element you could capture it in a closure:

```
$('#test').live('click',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/'
        data: { },
        success: function(mes) {
            $this.append('mes');
        }
    });
});
```

or if you don't like closures you could pass it as a key/value pair of the request:

```
$('#test').live('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/'
        data: { },
        myElement: $(this),
        success: function(mes) {
            this.myElement.append('mes');
        }
    });
});
```

This could be useful in scenarios where the `success` callback is not an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `this` will be the extended settings object used in the AJAX call. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to
>   `$.ajax`).

You can use the `context` setting to specify the object `this` will refer to in callbacks:

```
$("#test").live("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        context: this,
        success: function(mes) {
            // Here, this will refer to #test.
            $(this).append('mes');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is context. From [JQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):
The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In that example, `$(this)` would represent the `$.ajax()` object.