# jQuery looping with .each and using selectors with $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm currently having to extend an very old ASP.NET site which has a database generated front end and is a behemoth of an application, it needs completely rewriting - however I've been told to add to it than redevelop it - rats!

Okay the backend renders the following table on the front end:

```
<table id="tableID">
<tr>
    <td class="qCol">
    <!-- Label here -->
    </td>

    <td class="qCo2">
    <!-- img here -->
    <!-- and a text box -->
    </td>

    <td class="qCo3">
    <!-- select menu here -->
    </td>

    <td class="qCo4">
    <!-- radio buttons here -->
    </td>

    <td class="qCo5">
    <!-- select menu here -->
    </td>

    <td class="qCo6">
    <!-- hidden validation image here -->
    </td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Now (Please don't ask why) I have to overwrite content of the td with the class "qCol" with the contents of the td with the class "qCo5".

This is a pretty easy affair using jQuery:

```
$('#tableID td.qCol').html($('#tableID td.aCo5').html());
```

Now I've amended the backend so more rows are generated for the table, none of these rows have an id and I need to do this HTML overwrite between the tds for each row (there will be 4 rows in total).

I know how to do this using JavaScript and a bit of looping but I want to get into the habit of using jQuery to do this, incorporating the .each() method.

I'm confused how I'd use "`this`" and then select the appropriate td, for example...

```
$('#tableID tr').each(function () {
      $(this).find('td .qCol').html($(this).find('td.aCo5').html());
});
```

What's the best way to do this?

If this question is poorly explained please say so and I'll expand

Comment: $('#tableID tr').each(function () {
      $(this).children('.qCol').html($(this).siblings('.aCo5').html());
});

Comment: actually saying that it may be: 
$('#tableID tr').each(function () { $(this).children('.qCol').html($(this).children('.aCo5').html()); });

Comment: [More than you ever wanted to know about `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149) should hopefully help clarify what `this` is

Comment: @Mark Sandman - Your suggestion should work fine, although you may want to remove the space between `td` and `.qCol` in the first `find` (I'm assuming it was just a typo).

Comment: @rickyduck - It would be the 2nd example. `this` will still refer to the current `tr` element inside the `html` method, so `siblings` will not work.

Comment: So are there many tables (without `id`s) that you always want to repalce `td.qCol` with `td.qCo5`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they've worked a treat - now how do I award the points for comments?

Comment: Press the up button :) @James Allardice, thought so... only   this   if inside a function.. long day!

Comment: You do not get points for comments; only answers. Although there is a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) for up-voted comments :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tableID tr').each(function () {    
    $(this).children('.qCol').html($(this).children('.aCo5').html()); 
});
```

As an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will replace the `qCol` with `qCo5` for *any* `<table>`

```
$('table tr td.qCol').each(function () {
    var qCo5 = $(this).nextAll('td.qCo5');
    $(this).html(qCo5.html());
});
```

The main selector just grabs all the `td.qCol` elements and then uses [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find the corresponding `td.qCo5` sibling in the same `<table>` and copies the contents to `$(this)` which in this context is `td.qCol`.

Comment: a much more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('#tableID tr').each(function () {
      $(this).children('td.qCol').html($(this).children('td.qCo5').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `each()` function allows you to do it a bit differently, without the `this`. Like so:

```
$('#tableID tr').each(function (i, row) {
    var row = $(row);
    row.find('td .qCol').html(row.find('td.aCo5').html());
});
```