# Whats wrong with this code in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

```
var x = "window.Something";

alert(window.x)
```

when i try this code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XJEGU/, it alerts undefined. While when i run this code in my browser, it works fine, can anybody tell what jsfiddle does with this code for such behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSFiddle wraps code in a function. This means that `x` is scoped locally to that function.

[image: Like so…]

Comment: I'm not surprised. That isn't the default though.

Comment: oh!! thanx, i am so silly, i should have looked it in firebug before asking. will accept this in 4 minutes as  SO is saying so!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to embed a variable to the window.
You can use this http://jsfiddle.net/XJEGU/3/

Comment: i know this, iam not trying to do that, i wanted to know why that didnt work!!