# javascript class - this.method called with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript class

```
function MyClass() {

  MyClass.prototype.fooMethod = function () {
    // some logic goes here...
  }

  MyClass.prototype.fooMethod2 = function () {
    this.fooMethod();
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected when I call like this:

```
var m = MyClass();
m.fooMethod2();
```

However when I have this code called by setInterval I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'fooMethod'"

```
var m = MyClass();
var intervalId = setInterval(m.fooMethod2, 100);
```

Is there any way I can use setInverval to call my method?

Comment: @Alex Wayne is correct, but to help enlighten you as to why, you may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
  m.fooMethod2();
}, 100);
```

In javascript, context (the value of `this`) is set by how the method is invoked.  So `foo.bar()` will set `this` to `foo` inside the `bar` function.

But when you return a a reference to a function to be run by something else, context is not preserved.  Check this out:

```
var callLater = function(fn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fn(); // no defined context, `this` will revert to the default: `window` 
  }, 1000);
};
callLater(foo.bar);
```

In this snippet, we pass a function into the `callLater` function.  But when we invoke `fn()` we do it without any *receiver*, meaning we lose context.

So anytime function context is important, you have to pass in an anonymous function that will call the method on an object explicitly.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't familiar with how to preserve the context, still somewhat new to javascript.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = new MyClass();
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){m.fooMethod2();}, 100);
```

Always use the `new` keyword when referencing an object, or you'll wind up with unexpected errors.

Comment: Jeez! How did I not spot that! Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Pass context as parameter. Then all will works perfectly.

```
module.exports = {
   lobby = [],
   init: function () {
      var parent = this;
      setInterval(function () {
        ref.everySecondTick(parent);
      }, 2000);
   },
   everySecondTick: function (parent) {
        console.log(parent.lobby.length);
   }
}
```