# AJAX username validation in Django

Tags: ajax, django, forms, validation

I want to create asynchronous username validation,
where upon change of the value of the username input, the database is accessed to see if that username is valid for use. So far I have this code, which doesn't seem to work. Please help me in finding out where things went wrong. Thanks!

My HTML:

```
<div>Username</div>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<div id="idval"></div>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
function CheckId() {
$.get('/signup/', {username: $(this).val()},
    function(data){
        if(data == "True"){
            $('#idval').html("You may use this ID");
        } else {
            $('#idval').html("Unavailable");
        }
});
}
function onChange(){
 $("#id").change( function() {CheckId()});
}
$(document).ready(onChange);
</script>
```

My View:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        p = request.GET.copy()
        if p.has_key('username'):         
            name = p['username']
            if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=name):
                return HttpResponse(False)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(True)
```

Comment: `this` inside CheckId is not what you think it is. Everything else should work.

Comment: I did change this to '#id' but I am now always getting Unavailable.. any ideas?? Even when I change the username to an available one..

Answer (score 3):

in `CheckId()` `$(this).val()` isn't going to work. You need `$('#id').val()`

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134149/968269) of how the `this` keyword works

Comment: Actually now #idval always shows Unavailable even when I change to usernames that are available. Can you help me on that? Thanks!!!