# isNaN giving confusing results

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a HTML form that does some simple calculation if the input is a number. However, my number input is not being regarded by the javascript function as a number. I am confused why this is so and did some testing with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vS8P/) using the following code

**HTML**

```
<form>
 <input name=a type=number value='' oninput='checka();'>
 <input name=b type=number value='' oninput='checkb(this);'>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function checka() {
 alert(isNaN(document.forms[0].a.value));
}

function checkb(A) {
 alert(isNaN(this.value));
}
```

I am dumbfounded by the result. The `checka` function works normally giving false when '5' is entered and true when 'a' is entered. However, the `checkb` function gives true for both cases.

I understand from [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) that `isNaN` function may do type conversion first before checking the input whether it is a number or not:

> Confusing special-case behavior
>
> Since the very earliest versions of the isNaN function specification,
>   its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the
>   argument to the isNaN function is not a number, the value is first
>   coerced to a number. The resulting value is then tested to determine
>   whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric
>   type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string
>   and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or
>   one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string,
>   for example, is surely "not a number." The confusion stems from the
>   fact that the term, "not a number", has a specific meaning for numbers
>   represented as IEEE-794 floating-point values. The function should be
>   interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to
>   a numeric value, an IEEE-794 'Not A Number' value?"

How does this help to explain the phenomenon that I am seeing? Or is this another form of confusion not related to type conversion?

Comment: Don't you mean `A.value` in `checkb` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` (when you call `checkb`) is `window`…

(You call `checkb(this)` without a parent object (`foo.checkb`) so the context is `window` automatically. For further reading, see [How does “this” keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal).)

…so `this.value` is `window.value` which is (presumably) `undefined` and thus is not a number.

You don't do anything with the `this` that you pass to `checkb()` — the function doesn't do anything with any of its arguments.

You probably meant:

```
function checkb(A) {
 alert(isNaN(A.value));
}
```

Comment: sorry, why is `this` `window` and not `input`?

Comment: But, I didn't make the same mistake in the HTML form I am working on. Don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`this.value` is undefined, this is the window object, not the input.

If you want to use this to point to the input, you need to assign the event handlers in an unobtrusive manner.

```
<form>
 <input name=b type=number value='' id="b">
</form>

<script>    
 function checkb(A) {
  alert(isNaN(this.value));
 }    
 document.getElementById("b").oninput = checkb;  //better to use an addEventListener
</script>
```