# Problems with undefined variable in object structure

Tags: javascript

I have this class structure (more or less):

```
function DataLoader = function () {
    this.setup = function () {
        this.page = new Page();
        this.page.setup();
    };

    Page = function () {
        this.apiSelect = null;
        this.onchangelistener = function () {
            //---------------- look here ---------------
            console.log(this.apiSelect); //Why is this.apiSelect undefined?
            //---------------- look here ---------------
        };

        this.setup = function () {
            this.apiSelect = document.getElementById("foo");
            //This is also weird to me, I had to do it like this
            //to get the functionality I wanted...
            document.getElementById("foo").onchange = this.onchangelistener;
        };
    };
};

var dl = new DataLoader();
dl.setup();
```

I am very new to Javascript and don't now much of the nitty gritty details yet, but this seems very strange to me. When the onchange event fires it calls onchangelistener. How come that this.apiSelect is undefinded? I mean i have allready added a value to it.

My current code looks like this

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149)

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ...
 Page = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.apiSelect = null;
        this.onchangelistener = function () {
            console.log(self.apiSelect);
        };
```

inside `onchangelistener` function the reference of `this` is not the same of `this` in the outer scope. So you need to create a reference to the outer `this` (with `var self = this;`) and use it inside the function

Answer (score 0):

```
Page = function () {
        var apiSelect = null;
        this.onchangelistener = function () {
            console.log(apiSelect);
        };
        ...
};
```

This was happening because `this` was being bound to the new 'internal' function and it had no idea what the `apiSelect` data member was.