# NodeJS: use module.exports in function from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Simple example:

```
file1

module.exports.foo = function(obj) {
  module.exports.obj = obj;
}

file2

file1 = require("file1")
var something = {a: "a"};
file1.foo(something); //export "something" being a part of file2
```

The example above is not working.

What I want is basically a module.exports helper, since I plan a few helpers for whole object "exportion".

Thank you

Comment: What error, you are getting ?

Comment: The code you have posted works exactly as you seem to expect. Test case: `var f2 = require('./file2');
var f1 = require('./file1');
console.log(f1.obj);` outputs `{ a: 'a' }`.

Comment: When I try to access the "file2" module from a third file, the "file2" module is empty. I want to export objects from file2, but the act of export is happning in a function inside file1.

Comment: Why don't you just `return obj;` in the `foo` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module` in `file1.js` is a different instance from that in `file2.js`.

file1.js

```
module.exports.foo = function(obj) {
    module.exports.obj = obj; 
    return module;
}
```

file2.js

```
console.log("running file2");

file1 = require("./file1");

var something = {a: "a"}; 
var moduleOfFile1 = file1.foo(something); //export "something" being a part of file2 

console.log("file1 module: " + moduleOfFile1.id);
console.log("file2 module: " + module.id);
```

console:

```
node file2.js
```

`id` returned are different

---

**Update**

alternatively, why not update file2.js to extend its `module.exports`

File2.js

```
// well, you may copy `extend` implementation if you 
// do not want to depend on `underscore.js`
var _ = require("underscore");     
file1 = require("./file1");  

_.extend(module.exports, file1);

var something = {a: "a"};  
// or do something else

_.extend(module.exports, {
    obj: something
});
```

File3.js

```
file2 = require("./file2.js");
console.log(file2.obj.a);
```

Comment: Another question: why is "this" an empty object outside a function? I though the "module.exports" would belong to "this".

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) may help you understand the confusing `this` in JavaScript. In summary, the value of `this` depends on where it's accessed.