# Why the property of this cannot be accessed directlly within a private function in a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, language-design

In my own answer for [A JavaScript VM that interprets code written in JSON](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/a-javascript-vm-that-interprets-code-written-in-json) I stated that the "public" properties of a JavaScript closure cannot be accessed in a "private" function.

The example given in that post is

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        //publicfunction(); //wrong; you have no access to it
        console.log(this); //refer to the global object, not the object creating
    };
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }
}
```

I think the reason is for some backward compatibility issues `privatefunction` must belong to the global object. So the public function is only an anonymous function that assigned to a property of `this`. This explains why calling `publicfunction` will fail because it need to have a reference to `this` first.

However, the following fix is still not work:

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        //publicfunction(); //wrong; you have no access to it
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }.bind(this);
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }
}
```

As I explicitly specify that `privatefunction` should be bound with the object creating, calling `publicfunction` should work but it does not. I have to do the following:

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        this.publicfunction();
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }.bind(this);
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }
}
```

Another workaround (the way that I am using) is the following:

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        publicfunction();
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    };
    var publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this); //refer to the object creating
    }
    this.publicfunction = publicfunction;
}
```

Now is the question part. What is the reason behind this behavior? What is it trying to avoid by disabling access `this`'s properties without explicit specification?

UPDATE: the main part of the question is : When the interpreter cannot find a name in the scope chains, why should'nt it have a look at the `this` properties?

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding of how scope works in javascript. You could take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: There is nothing to do with the scope, the major problem is why when JavaScript cannot find a name it do not have a look at the `this` object?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the reference `this` is determined by the caller of the function/method, for example:

```
function anobject(){
    // here "this" is the object
    var privatefunction = function(){
        // here "this" is the object **that called privatefunction()**
    };
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        // this method will always be called by the object, so "this" is the object
    }
}
```

To achieve what you want you could also try this:

```
function anobject(){
    var that = this;
    var privatefunction = function(){
        [do what you like using "that"]
    };
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        [here you can use "this" directly, or "that"]
    }
}
```

See also how javascript scope works, here [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) and on the web.

Comment: I have almost explained this in my post. PLEASE read carefully. Anyway, you have provided another workaround.

Comment: Technology you said `privatefunction`'s this is the object that called it. This is not true. If I define another public function and let it call `privatefunction`, `this` is still the global object if I call the public function in global scope in my test.

Comment: As I said in my answer, when you call `privatefunction()`, even inside the object, since you're **not** calling it as `this.privatefunction()` (which would be impossible since it is not a method of that object) then `this` inside the function is the global object. If I am not clear enough please tell me and I'll try to explain it better when I have a moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, `publicfunction()` is delcared as a **property** of the object `this`:

```
this.publicfunction = function(){
    console.log(this);
}
```

Therefore, this function is not directly accessible by its name `publicfunction()`, and that is independent of the context. The function does not actually belong to any context, but rather to the *object of which it is a property*.

In your example, when `privatefunction()` calls `publicfunction()`, this raises an error because there is no function declared as a **variable** with the name `publicfunction()`, and **not** because `this`'s properties are not accessible:

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        //publicfunction(); // You cannot call publicfunction() because there is
                            // no function defined with this name
    }.bind(this);
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Look at this example, `publicfunction()` is not accessible even within `anobject()`:

```
function anobject(){
    this.publicfunction = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    // publicfunction(); // Wrong because publicfunction()
                         // was not defined as a variable
}
```

However, if `publicfunction()` was defined as a **variable** within the context of `anobject()`, then this function would be accessible by its name. For example you can simply declare `function publicfunction()` within the closure of `anobject()`:

```
function anobject(){
    function publicfunction() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    publicfunction(); // You can access publicfunction() here
}
```

But in this case, `publicfunction()` is not accessible outside the execution context of `anobject()`, therefore it can be regarded as a 'private' function:

```
var a = new anobject();
if(typeof a.publicfunction === 'undefined')
    console.log('Public function is undefined outside of anobject()');
```

As a result, that's why we use the `this` keyword to declare `publicfunction()`: it makes it accessible outside the context of `anobject()`, but doing so define this function only as a **property** of `anobject()`.

Therefore the only way to access this function is by calling `this.publicfunction()`:

```
function anobject(){
    var privatefunction = function(){
        this.publicfunction();
        console.log(this);
    }.bind(this);
    this.publicfunction = function(){
        console.log(this);
   }
}
```

More details regarding the `this` keyword: [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Variable vs. Properties in JavaScript: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/

Comment: Fine. Do you mean that in JavaScript a name without object prefix  will ALWAYS refer to a variable, not properties of any object?