# "This" keyword in javascript & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning jQuery, and just started implementing `"this"` keyword.  I understand what it does in jQuery, but does it have the same functionality in javascript, as a scope reference?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not some jQuery magic, it is a JavaScript keyword.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly can `this` be used for? Sometimes I try to implement it but find that it returns the wrong value/variable/element.

Comment: while this may not be magic - i think it's pretty magical especially when var that = this;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `this` keyword in JavaScript still means the element in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation: `this` is the context of a function that can change depending on how that function is called. For example:

```
function myfunc() {
  console.log(this.toString());
}

myfunc(); //=> [object Window] 
myfunc.call('Hello World'); //=> Hello World
```

When using prototypes, `this` refers to the current instance. In jQuery it works something like this (very simplified):

```
(function(win) {

  // Constructor
  function jQuery(selector) {

  }

  // Shortcut to create news instances
  function $(selector) {
    return new jQuery(selector);
  }

  // Public methods
  jQuery.prototype = {

    // All methods 'return this' to allow chaining
    // 'this' is the jQuery instance
    method: function() {
      return this;
    }

  };

  win.$ = $; // expose to user

}(window));
```

So when you do this `$(this)` you're just creating a new jQuery instance of whatever `this` refers to (usually a DOM element) so you can inherit the prototype and use the public methods.