# How to have one member of a javascript object refer to another member of same object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

While defining an object in javascript, is there a way for a member of that object to access the value of another member of the same object? For example if I am defining the below (using jquery)

```
var x = $.extend({}, {
  greeting: 'hello',
  message: this.greeting+' world'
});

alert(x.message);
```

This above code would alert `undefined world`. How do I make it take the value of `greeting` during the definition. In this case the expected output is `hello world`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: `this` in that case is the window, not the object, and since the object isn't defined anywhere yet, there isn't anything to reference yet. So, no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 8):

You can use properties:

```
var foo = {
    greeting: 'hello',
    get message() {
        return this.greeting+' world'
    }
};

console.log(foo.message);
foo.greeting = 'hi';
console.log(foo.message);
```

Although I'm not sure how these will interact with `$.extend`

In older browsers, you could always just make `message` a function, rather than a property getter

Comment: This is a nice way to do it, but it won't work in old browsers.

Comment: Wow, how long have these been available?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
var x = $.extend({}, {
  greeting: 'hello',
  message: function(){
     return this.greeting+' world';
  }
});

alert(x.message);
```

Comment: Sorry, the @Eric answered first!

Comment: You're not invoking `x.message`, you should use `console.log` over `alert` for debugging.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I just paste the same code with the modification.

Comment: This should read `alert(x.message());`

Answer (score 0):

You can create some `Constructor` function. Inside this function `this.greeting` will be defined.

```
var Constructor = function () {
   this.greeting = 'hello',
   this.message = this.greeting + ' world'
   return this;
};
```

And then extend your object with instance of `Constructor`:

```
var x = $.extend({}, new Constructor());
```

Comment: You are right too, but in this case he is using a literal object.

Comment: I guess, it's just a code snippet. I think, that this method is a good choice, if having a literal object is not mandatory.

Comment: There's no need to `return this` here

Comment: @Eric Really! The scope of the function already does this by default