# this.emit is not working but self.emit is working. why?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

The following node.js script is not working

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

var TickE = function() {    
}

util.inherits(TickE, EventEmitter); //TickE.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

TickE.prototype.ticker = function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval (function () {
         self.emit('tick');      
    }, 1000);
};

var t = new TickE ();

//console.log (util.inspect(t));

t.on('tick', function() { console.log ('Tick...');});

t.ticker();
```

It is not working if I call the emit method like below

```
TickE.prototype.ticker = function() {
    //var self = this; // commented this line
    setInterval (function () {
         this.emit('tick'); // using this in place of self
    }, 1000);
};
```

self is just a variable holding reference of this and why this is throwing error ?

Comment: This has been asked so very often before. Please search for `this` and `javascript` on Google. You should get *tons* of results.

Comment: @Golo: that might be the problem - can you suggest a good and *correct* reading?

Comment: E.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/a/134149/1333873 ... section "As a function"

Comment: you can solve this problem by using new ES2015 arrow functions.

Answer (score 6):

Because [the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has a different value in the function that is invoked by [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).

You already know the solution with the `self` variable in a closure, a different (and shorter) solution would be [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the emit method:

```
setInterval(this.emit.bind(this, "tick"), 1000);
```