# javascript object properties using properties of self

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign a value to an object property using a property of the current object being decalred?

```
var myObject = new Object({ 
    a: 1, 
    b: 2, 
    c: this.a + this.b // is this possible ? ( or even myObject.a + myObject.c)
});
```

I know I could just declare it as below but is it possible as above?

```
myObject.c = myObject.a + myObject + b;
```

Comment: Why haven't you tried that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ --> try --> see what happens.

Comment: @VisioN — Presumably, he has, and it hasn't worked, so he is asking if there is some other syntax that does work.

Comment: The code in the linked dupe is almost identical to yours, did you copy it from there?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That doesn't really make sense until you finally answer your own question and get rep out of that.

Comment: @Quentin That may be. I think you shouldn't delete the answer, even though the question is duplicate.

Comment: That "duplicate question" wasn't listed in the suggested questions when I posted this question. 
@VisioN You are correct, I have tried both in jsfiddle but no joy.

Comment: @Ian OK fair enough. You should have said that you did try and what errors you got otherwise it just looks like you're asking before trying.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Cheers for the notice. Still, amazing coincidence the code is identical to the "dupe" question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple console log should have shown you why your code works but gives a `NaN`. After modifying your code to the sample below and running it:

```
var myObject = new Object({
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
     c: console.log(this.a + this.b)
});
myObject.c;
```

the result was: `NaN` why? When you created `myObject` `this` was bound to the `document` object which apparently doesn't have properties `a` and `b`.Perhaps this will work for you:

```
var myObject = new Object({
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
     c: function () {
         return this.a + this.b;
     }
});
myObject.c();
```

Check this out question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) to understand more about `this` within a javascript object literal