# Why 'this' in object function is different when called directly from addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Why does calling an object function straight from an addEventListener make `this` point to calling element, but calling from a third party function makes `this` point to the object and NOT the third party function?

```
var obj = {
    me: 'obj',
    objFunction: function(){
        document.body.innerHTML += this.me;
    }
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', obj.objFunction);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', thirdParty);

function thirdParty(){
    obj.objFunction();
}
```

The above code will print `undefined` on mousedown and `'obj'` on mouseup.
http://jsfiddle.net/ana353Lk/1/

Guess I'm curious if there is an advantage to why it works this way...

Comment: See also [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) and the documentation about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and [Using this inside an event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17665489/218196)

Comment: @slebetman: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @FelixKling: While the question is not a duplicate of this question the answer is also an answer to this question. Which in Stackoverflow is the definition of "duplicate".

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: My answer is more complete and more frequently updated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', obj.objFunction);
```

You are only passing a reference to the `objFunction` function.  There is no reference at all to `obj` passed.  So, when the event system calls the callback `objFunction` is just calls it as a normal function no different than this:

```
 var fn = obj.objFunction;
 fn();
```

Thus, the context of the object is lost entirely and the method is just called as if it was a normal function.  There are several work-arounds.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {return obj.objFunction(e)});
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', obj.objFunction.bind(obj));
```

Both of these work-arounds create a small stub function that is what the event handler calls and then the stub turns around and calls `obj.objFuntion()` with the appropriate object reference which causes `this` to be set to `obj`.

---

In case you aren't familiar with how `this` is set in javascript, it's worth some reading on that.  Here's [one reference](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) and [another reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  How `this` is set is determined by how a function is called (not by how the function is defined).  In a nutshell, there are these cases:

1. Normal function call `fn()` - `this` is set to the global object or `undefined` (in strict mode).
2. Method call `obj.method()` - `this` is set to `obj` inside the method.
3. Using `fn.apply(x)` or `fn.call(x)` - `this` is set by the first argument to `.apply()` or `.call()`.
4. Using `var newFn = fn.bind(x)` - When `newFn()` is called, `this` is set to the first argument passed to `.bind()`.
5. Using `new` with a constructor function as in `var x = new Fn();` - In the constructor function `this` will be set to a newly created object of the `Fn` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bind = function bind(context, name) {
    return function () {
        return context[name].apply(context, arguments);
    };
};

var obj = {
    me: 'obj',
    objFunction: function () {
        document.body.innerHTML += this.me;
    }
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', bind(obj, "objFunction"));
document.addEventListener('mouseup', thirdParty);

function thirdParty() {
    obj.objFunction();
}
```