# PointerLockControls.js - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lock') at HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, three.js, pointerlock

I'm extremely new to Javascript and Three.js (and to posting on stackOverflow). I'm attempting to implement a first person camera using three.js by converting the example implementation of PointerLockControls.js found here:
[PointerLockControls example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html)

My issue is that the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lock')
at HTMLDivElement.' is thrown - caused by line 204 of my code (full code below) which reads:

```
 // initialise locks: 
    const blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
    const instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );
        
    instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    // LINE 204: ERROR
    this.controls_.lock;
    } );
```

The example defines this lock as:

```
instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

                    controls.lock();

                } );
```

I understand that this error stems from the fact that, at runtime, `this.controls_` is undefined. I create and assign `this.controls_` before adding this event listener. But when I test to see whether `this.controls_` is undefined at the point 'this.controls_.lock' is called, `this.controls_` is undefined.

Is there a reason `this.controls_` is undefined within the event listener? Does the listener need to function independently of the `FirstPersonCamereaDemo` class that `controls_` is defined in?

Previously, I analogously defined

```
instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
            this.controls_.lock();
        } );
```

where `PointerCamera.lock` was defined as

```
lock() {
       this.controls.lock();
}
```

I've attempted to redefine my lock functions using `const = function () {...}`, which led to the type error occurring in the PointerLockControls.js file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full Javascript:

```
import * as THREE from '../three.js-r134/three.js-r134/build/three.module.js';
import { FirstPersonControls } from '../three.js-r134/three.js-r134/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';
import { PointerLockControls } from '../three.js-r134/three.js-r134/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js';

// class for handling the camera

// camera implemented using the example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=pointerlock#misc_controls_pointerlock


// listener is domElement used to listen for mouse/touch events
class PointerCamera {
    constructor(camera, dElement, objects) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.dElement = dElement
        this.objects = objects;
        this.raycaster = null;
        this.moveForward = false;
        this.moveBackward = false;
        this.moveLeft = false;
        this.moveRight = false;
        this.canJump = false;
        this.controls = null;

        //minHeight initialised to initial value of y-coordinate of camera
        this.minHeight = camera.position.y;


        // this.prevTime
        // may not need this if we pass it to the update from update in the main render

        this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
        this.direction = new THREE.Vector3();
        this.vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        this.color = new THREE.Color();

        // initialise movement
        this.dElement.addEventListener( 'keydown', this.onKeyDown);
        this.dElement.addEventListener( 'keyup', this.onKeyUp);

        this.initControls();
    }

    initControls() {
        this.controls = new PointerLockControls(this.camera, this.dElement);

        // locks
        this.lock = function () {
            this.controls.lock();
        }

        this.unlock = function () {
            this.controls.unlock();
        }
    }

    changeMinHeight(newHeight) {
        const oldHeight = this.minHeight;
        this.minHeight = newHeight;

        return oldHeight;
    }

    // keydown function
    onKeyDown( event ) {

        switch ( event.code ) {

            case 'ArrowUp':
            case 'KeyW':
                this.moveForward = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowLeft':
            case 'KeyA':
                this.moveLeft = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowDown':
            case 'KeyS':
                this.moveBackward = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowRight':
            case 'KeyD':
                this.moveRight = true;
                break;

            case 'Space':
                if ( canJump === true ) velocity.y += 350;
                this.canJump = false;
                break;

        }
    }
    
    //keyupfunction
    //if domElement doesn't work, try passing full document to the class.

    onKeyUp = function ( event ) {

        switch ( event.code ) {

            case 'ArrowUp':
            case 'KeyW':
                this.moveForward = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowLeft':
            case 'KeyA':
                this.moveLeft = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowDown':
            case 'KeyS':
                this.moveBackward = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowRight':
            case 'KeyD':
                this.moveRight = false;
                break;

        }

    }

    update(timeElapsedS) {

        if (this.controls.isLocked === true) {

            // to adjust vertical acceleration, need to calculate whether on the ground or not.
            const delta = timeElapsedS; // time elapsed in seconds

            // may need to double check this hits 0.
            this.velocity.x -= this.velocity.x * 10 * delta;
            this.velocity.z -= this.velocity.z * 10 * delta;

            // simulate gravity: 
            this.velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100 * delta; // 100.0 = mass of player

            this.direction.z = Number(this.moveForward) - Number(this.moveBackward);
            this.direction.x = Number(this.moveRight) - Number(this.moveLeft);
            this.direction.normalize(); // ensures consistent movement in all directions


            if (this.moveForward || this.moveBackward) this.velocity.z -= this.direction.z * 400 * delta;
            if (this.moveLeft || this.moveRight) this.velocity.x -= this.direction.x * 400 * delta;


            // add object interaction with ray casting here
            
            // update camera position: 
            this.controls.moveRight( - this.velocity.x * delta);
            this.controls.moveForward( - this.velocity.z * delta);

            this.controls.getObject().position.y += ( this.velocity.y * delta ); // new behavior

            // detect if camera falls below minimum: 

            if ( controls.getObject().position.y < 10 ) {
                this.velocity.y = 0;
                this.controls.getObject().position.y = 10;
                this.canJump = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

class FirstPersonCameraDemo {
    constructor() {
        this.initialize_();
    }

    initialize_() {
        this.initializeRenderer_();
        this.initializeLights_();
        this.initializeScene_();
        this.initializeDemo_();

        this.previousRAF_ = null;
        this.raf_();
        this.onWindowResize_();
    }

    initializeDemo_() {
        this.controls_ = new PointerCamera(this.camera_, document.body, []);
        this.controls_.controls.lookSpeed = 0.8;
        this.controls_.controls.movementSpeed = 5;
        this.controls_.controls.heightCoef = 0;
        // const controlLock = function () {this.controls_.lock};

        // initialise locks: 
        const blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
        const instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );
        
        instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
            this.controls_.lock;
        } );

        this.controls_.controls.addEventListener( 'lock', function () {
            instructions.style.display = 'none';
            blocker.style.display = 'none';
        } );

        this.controls_.controls.addEventListener( 'unlock', function () {
            blocker.style.display = 'block';
            instructions.style.display = '';
        } );
        
        this.scene_.add(this.controls_.controls.getObject());
    }

    initializeRenderer_() {
        this.threejs_ = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: false,
        });
        this.threejs_.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this.threejs_.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.threejs_.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.threejs_.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.threejs_.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
        this.threejs_.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    
        document.body.appendChild(this.threejs_.domElement);

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.onWindowResize_();
        }, false);


        // initialise CAMERA
        this.minHeight = 10;
        const fov = 60;
        const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        const near = 1.0;
        const far = 1000.0;
        this.camera_ = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        // minimum and default height (10 - change to variable later)
        this.camera_.position.set(0, this.minHeight, 0);

        this.scene_ = new THREE.Scene();
    }

    initializeScene_() {
        const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
        const texture = loader.load([
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_right1.png',
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_left2.png',
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_top3.png',
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_bottom4.png',
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_front5.png',
            './bkg/bkg/red/bkg1_back6.png'
        ]);

        this.scene_.background = texture;

        const planegeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 10, 10);
        // plane.castShadow = false;
        // plane.receiveShadow = true;
        planegeo.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh( planegeo, material );
        this.scene_.add(plane);
    }

    initializeLights_() { 

        // his light: 
    const distance = 50.0;
    const angle = Math.PI / 4.0;
    const penumbra = 0.5;
    const decay = 1.0;

    let light = new THREE.SpotLight(
        0xFFFFFF, 100.0, distance, angle, penumbra, decay);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.bias = -0.00001;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 4096;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 4096;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 1;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 100;

    light.position.set(25, 25, 0);
    light.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    this.scene_.add(light);

    const upColour = 0xFFFF80;
    const downColour = 0x808080;
    light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(upColour, downColour, 0.5);
    light.color.setHSL( 0.6, 1, 0.6 );
    light.groundColor.setHSL( 0.095, 1, 0.75 );
    light.position.set(0, 4, 0);
    this.scene_.add(light);
    }

    onWindowResize_() {
        this.camera_.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        this.camera_.updateProjectionMatrix();

        this.threejs_.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    raf_() {
        requestAnimationFrame((t) => {
            if (this.previousRAF_ === null) {
              this.previousRAF_ = t;
            }
      
            this.step_(t - this.previousRAF_);
            this.threejs_.autoClear = true;
            this.threejs_.render(this.scene_, this.camera_);
            console.log("just tried to render");
            this.threejs_.autoClear = false;
            this.previousRAF_ = t;
            this.raf_();
          }); 
    }

    step_(timeElapsed) {
        // console.log("in demo step");
        const timeElapsedS = timeElapsed * 0.01;
        // may need to change above to 0.001

        this.controls_.update(timeElapsedS);
    }
}

// run
let _APP = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log("successful print");
    _APP = new FirstPersonCameraDemo();
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Trying to get basic FPS control</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }

            #blocker {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }

            #instructions {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;

                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="blocker">
            <div id="instructions">
                <p style="font-size:36px">
                    Click to play
                </p>
                <p>
                    Move: WASD<br/>
                    Jump: SPACE<br/>
                    Look: MOUSE
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="module" src="./fpsbasic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When the event listener is triggered, the `this` is actually `instructions`, which is an `HTMLElement`, which would not contain `.controls` or `.lock` at all. In your example, you can see they are not pointing to `this.controls.lock`, but to `controls.lock`, which was defined as `controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body )`, which is an THREEjs object that _does_ have those properties.

Comment: @somethinghere Thank You - A solution I've just found is to bind 'this' through both definitions of the lock functions which allows each listener to access the correct 'this'

Comment: Happy that worked, but I do feel you might have used a hacky solution here. Looking at the example the simplicity is that is is a global variable that you can access from any method defined in the same scope. I mean, if it works for you, fine, but take your example to heart to produce some clean, understandable code. You will find it much easier to understand when you come back later!

Comment: @somethinghere I agree it feels quite hacky. However, my goal was to be able to have the two classes `FirstpersonCameraDemo` and `PointerCamera` in separate files, so that a single `.js` file would contain the rendering code and import the functionality of `PointerCamera`. I'm not sure how to make a similar global variable function across files like that.

Comment: You could attach it to the window (which is global), or perhaps use imports/exports and module structures. But either way, happy you found a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to `bind` the correct `this` to each of the new `lock` functions so that each call has the appropriate scope to call `FirstPersonCameraDemo.controls_` and `PointerCamera.controls` appropriately.

The discussion [scope of handler functions in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375081/23273653) was very useful in understanding that the event handler functions would not have access to the correct 'this' belonging to the classes, but instead 'this' would refer to `instructions`.

The corrected definitions are:

within `FirstPersonCameraDemo`:

```js
instructions.addEventListener( 'click', this.controls_.lock2().bind(this));
```

Within 'PointerCamera':

```js
    initControls() {
        this.controls = new PointerLockControls(this.camera, this.dElement);

        // locks
        this.lock = function (e) {
            return this.controls.lock(e);
        }

        this.unlock = function () {
            this.controls.unlock();
        }
    }

    lock2() {return this.lock.bind(this)}
    unlock2() {return this.unlock.bind(this)}
```