# How to get event target/this without putting the event listener in the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, this

I'm not a big fan of putting my event listeners (specifically `onclick` in this case) in the HTML, mostly because I can't use

> $(document).ready(function(){})

I would much rather define the buttons' `onclick` as I've commented it in the `startup` function. However, `this` doesn't refer to the clicked button when I put the listener in the script (I'm guessing because it doesn't "know" which button I clicked). I've tried setting `event` as a parameter to the `showImage` function, and finding the `e.target` inside it, but this didn't work either. Is there a way I can refer to the clicked button without having the `onclick` inside the HTML tag?

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = startup;
  function startup() {
    $("img").hide();
    //$("button").click(showImage(this));
  }
  function showImage(e) {
    var chosen = e.value;
    $('#' + chosen).fadeIn(500);
    $('img:not(#' + chosen + ')').hide();
  }
//});
```

```css
body {background-color: #EFEFEF;}
#content {width: 80%; margin: auto; background-color: white; padding: 15px; font-family: "Century Gothic",sans-serif;}
img {height: 250px; border: solid 1px black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pig" src="http://www.igjerstad.no/sites/default/files/styles/nodeimage/public/field/image/gris-750-5.jpg?itok=TJa-iUVg">
<img id="cow" src="https://www.matmerk.no/cms/images/3675/1200/1200/ku-nyt-norge.jpeg">
<img id="sheep" src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103778879/630/472/image.jpg">
<img id="hen" src="http://africahitz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hen-white-and-black-color.jpg">
<br>
<button value="pig" onclick="showImage(this)">Gris</button>
<button value="cow" onclick="showImage(this)">Ku</button>
<button value="sheep" onclick="showImage(this)">Sau</button>
<button value="hen" onclick="showImage(this)">Høne</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. I would guess someone else has had this problem and maybe asked about it here. I did check if I could find a similar question on the site, but found nothing. However, I have failed to find that before, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

PS2. The images in my code are not mine, nor do I have the rights for them. Please don't sue me ':D

PS3(!!). I'm not an experienced programmer, my terminology might be wrong some places. Feel free to correct me :)

Comment: $('button').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); var selectedImage = $(this); showImage(selectedImage); });

Comment: or something like that

Comment: @Stender button with type="button" dont need e.preventDefault. That will the answer make a bit cleaner

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst It wasn't really an answer :) just my first thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to define function() in a click function so it should look like this:

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        //code to execute here
    });
```

Instead of this:

```
    $("button").click(//code to execute here);
```

When calling `this` in a button it will refer to the button and if I understand your code right, the image is hidden therefore if that is the button then you can't click a hidden image, if you're using a separate button to hide the image then in the click function you need to have `e` stated as the image element.

To use `this` you also need to call it as `$(this)` not just `this`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: It is important you understand the underlying issue you had, so I will state the obvious here. The example you have shown executes the function right as you are setting up the event handler. The example Harry gave you defines a function (but does not execute it) during the the process of attaching the event handler. This is what makes it work. You need to pass a reference to a function to be used once the button is clicked, rather then executing it whilst in the process of creating an event handler.

Comment: Hmm, using only `this` worked for me. Should it not have?

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be set inside the event handler as `event.currentTarget` [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17665649/427146). If you are using jQuery you can make a jQuery object from it by doing `$(this)`. So to get the `value` you can do:

```
var chosen = $(this).prop('value');
```

I have also added a class `myclass` to the buttons to select it using `$('.myclass')` so that this can be seperated from other possible buttons in the page. You can also do `$('button')` instead to select all buttons irrespective of the class.

**UPDATE**

Just saw your commented out code:

```
$("button").click(showImage(this)); // When a button is clicked
 // call the function returned by showImage(this).. err it doesnt return 
 // a function so it fails.
```

you should pass a function reference or simply a function name to the click event registration. like `.click(showImage)` without any function call `()`. In your code it will execute `showImage(this)` and bind the returned value to the event listener, which will apparently fail.

It should actually be:

```
$("button").click(showImage); // when a button is clicked
 // call the function showImage with this=<clicked button> and param=event
```

and `this` will be automatically set inside the function as `event.currentTarget`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = startup;
  function startup() {
    $("img").hide();
    //$("button").click(showImage(this));
  }
  function showImage(e) {
    var chosen = $(this).prop('value');
    $('#' + chosen).fadeIn(500);
    $('img:not(#' + chosen + ')').hide();
  }
  $('.myclass').on('click', showImage);
});
```

```css
body {background-color: #EFEFEF;}
#content {width: 80%; margin: auto; background-color: white; padding: 15px; font-family: "Century Gothic",sans-serif;}
img {height: 250px; border: solid 1px black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pig" src="http://www.igjerstad.no/sites/default/files/styles/nodeimage/public/field/image/gris-750-5.jpg?itok=TJa-iUVg">
<img id="cow" src="https://www.matmerk.no/cms/images/3675/1200/1200/ku-nyt-norge.jpeg">
<img id="sheep" src="https://media.timeout.com/images/103778879/630/472/image.jpg">
<img id="hen" src="http://africahitz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hen-white-and-black-color.jpg">
<br>
<button value="pig" class="myclass">Gris</button>
<button value="cow" class="myclass">Ku</button>
<button value="sheep" class="myclass">Sau</button>
<button value="hen" class="myclass">Høne</button>
```

Comment: That's very clever, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onload = startup(); 
  function startup() {
   console.log("window loaded");
    $("img").hide();
    $("button").click(function() {showImage(this)});
  }
  function showImage(e) {
    console.log("onside eras");
    var chosen = e.value;
    $('#' + chosen).fadeIn(500);
    $('img:not(#' + chosen + ')').hide();
  }   
//});
```