# React value in state never updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `to` value in my react app never updates.

I have the following code:

```
handleToChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        query: this.state.query,
        from: this.state.from,
        to: event.target.value,
        data: this.state.data,
        loading: this.state.loading,
    });
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.triggerChange();
}
```

`console.log(event.target.value)` correctly returns the value, but the state is not updated. I know this as the app never updates the `to` value. The other values of the state update correctly and I use the same method to update them.

Here is the whole class. (the Handler class is the interface that makes the translation request to a server)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Handler from '../Handler.js';

class Translator extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            query: '', from: 'en', to: 'es', data: {}, loading: false
        };

        this.handleQueryChange = this.handleQueryChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFromChange = this.handleFromChange.bind(this);
        this.handleToChange = this.handleToChange.bind(this);

        this.triggerChange = this.triggerChange.bind(this);
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    }

    async update() {

        this.setState({
            query: this.state.query, from: this.state.from, to: this.state.to, data: this.state.data, loading: true,
        });

        let api = await Handler.get();

        this.setState({
            query: this.state.query, from: this.state.from, to: this.state.to, data: api, loading: false
        });
    }

    triggerChange() {
        Handler.put(this.state.query, this.state.from, this.state.to);
        this.update();
    }

    handleQueryChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            query: event.target.value,
            from: this.state.from,
            to: this.state.to,
            data: this.state.data,
            loading: this.state.loading,
        });
    }

    handleFromChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            query: this.state.query,
            from: event.target.value,
            to: this.state.to,
            data: this.state.data,
            loading: this.state.loading,
        });
        this.triggerChange();
    }

    handleToChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            query: this.state.query,
            from: this.state.from,
            to: event.target.value,
            data: this.state.data,
            loading: this.state.loading,
        });
        this.triggerChange();
    }


    render() {

        const error_message = (
            <div>
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#error" className="btn btn-outline-danger">Error</button>

                <div className="collapse" id="error">
                    Oops your query was invalid, this may be because of
                    <ul>
                        <li><b>The query is nonsense/ word does not exist in the language</b></li>
                        <li>There was a connection error to the api server</li>
                        <li>Exceeded quota
                            <ul>
                                <li>To prevent abuse, WordReference only allows a certain number of requests per IP</li>
                                <li>Please wait until the quota is reset</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Bugs: something may be wrong with the code.. my
                            bad &#175;&#92;&#95;&#40;&#12484;&#41;&#95;&#47;&#175;</li>
                    </ul>
                    You can always click the link to see the translations on WordReference
                </div>
            </div>
        );


        const loading_bar = (
            <div>
                <div className="progress" style={{height: 10}}>
                    <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar"
                         aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={{width: '100%'}}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        let error = "";
        if (this.state.data['phrase'] === '{invalid}') {
            error = error_message;
        }

        let loading = "";
        if (this.state.loading) {
            loading = loading_bar;
        }


        return (
            <div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm">

                        <div className="input-box">
                            <div className="custom-control custom-control-inline">
                                From:
                                <select className="custom-select custom-select-sm" onChange={this.handleFromChange.bind(this)}
                                        defaultValue="en" disabled>
                                    <option value="en" selected>english</option>
                                    <option value="es">spanish</option>
                                    <option value="fr">french</option>
                                </select>

                                To:
                                <select className="custom-select custom-select-sm" onChange={this.handleToChange.bind(this)}
                                        defaultValue="es" disabled>
                                    <option value="en">english</option>
                                    <option value="es" selected>spanish</option>
                                    <option value="fr">french</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                            <br/><br/>

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <textarea className="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Text" rows="4"
                                          onChange={this.handleQueryChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <button onClick={this.triggerChange} className="btn btn-success">Go</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="col-sm">
                        <div className="output-box">

                            <br/><br/>
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-block">

                                    <div className="card-text">
                                        {this.state.data.phrase}
                                    </div>
                                    <br/><br/>

                                    <div className="card-footer">
                                        <a href={this.state.data.url} className="card-link">WordReference ></a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br/>

                <div>
                    {loading}
                </div>

                <div className="error-box text-danger">
                    {error}
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Translator;
```

Comment: In React `event` is not persistent, and `setState` is async (I believe). Try to use `event.persist()` as the first statement in function. Or save `event.target.value` in a local var and use it in `setState`.

Comment: [Quoting this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17665489/463206) *As per "JavaScript The Definitive Guide" book this refers to the event target which seems to wrong. **event.currentTarget** seems more logical as event handlers are invoked as the method of the HTML element object.*

Comment: need to see the whole class for this. but as was mentioned by wostex, setState() is asynchronous, so if you need to access values immediately then you need to use a Promise. in the code you posted, of course your console log would work because you have the value right there. but you may be incorrectly accessing state before the value is updated.

Comment: how you use the `handleToChange` function ?

Comment: @UmairAhmed I use it to update a value in the state. This value holds a two letter language code. See updated code above

Comment: @Jared I posted it above. Let me know if you can figure it out. Thanks!