# How does "this" work in a display description function, when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, this

I am learning JavaScript on Udemy and there is a task to write a code that displays content when a "view more" button is clicked.

I can't understand how `this` works in the display content code and how JavaScript understands what the variable `t` is. 
I found a solution in the QA section, but I am not sure how it works.
Apparently, the `for i++` loop code is necessary so that the code works for each button in a tab.

Questions:

1. How does `this` work here and why is it necessary?
2. How does JavaScript understand what `t` is?

```
let desctiptionTab = document.querySelectorAll('.description-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < desctiptionTab.length; i++) {
  desctiptionTab[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    Modal(this);
  });
}

function Modal(t) {
  overlay.style.display = 'block';
  t.classList.add('more-splash');
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
};
```

Comment: Well, `this` in an event handler is the object on which the event was triggered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17665489/476.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to achieve something on the `click` event of an HTML element. This is why you are attaching a click event using `addEventListener`.

Now, functions in JS have a run-time scope normally (unless you use `call`, `bind` or `apply` [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)), meaning that `this` value can change according to the context when the function is called. In your case, the value of `this` is the clicked HTML element, which you are using to pass to your `Modal(t)` as parameter `t`.

```js
document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, so the above function will console log 'hello' right?