# Move element with jQuery plugin - setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Why this code doesn't work?
I wrote This code but:

```
(function($){
$.fn.newsSlider = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.each( function() {
            $(this).each(function(){
                $(this).append($(this).children(":first-child").clone());
                $(this).children(":first-child").remove();
            });
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

}(jQuery));

With setInterval:
http://jsfiddle.net/OmidJackson/46UNg/
Without setInterval:
http://jsfiddle.net/OmidJackson/6bKWU/

Comment: are you really clear about every `$(this)` you use in your code?

Comment: A JSFiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for this problem

Comment: out of setInterval it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` has different meaning (the window object) inside the setTimeout function literal. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134149/1619738) for further info about `this` in different contexts.

The solution is to save a reference to `this` so you can use it inside the setTimeout.
See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/46UNg/11/).

Comment: Tnx :) now I know about this

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `this` as it currently has a value of `window`

```
var $this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.each( function() {
        $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).append($(this).children(":first-child").clone());
            $(this).children(":first-child").remove();
        });
    });
}, 3000);
```