# Javascript closure with new and this

Tags: javascript

I was playing with new, this, and JavaScript and I ran across something and I have no idea why JavaScript behaves this way. Any help wrapping my head around this would be great.

Lets say I have a function:

```
function X() {
    this.q = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };  

    console.log(this);
}
```

This works as I expect:

```
var x = new X();
=> X {q: function}

x.q();
=> X {q: function}
```

But this does not act like I would expect:

```
function func(f) {
    f();
}

var x = new X();
=> X {q: function}

func(x.q);
=> Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
// I expected this to return "X {q: function}"

// But this works...
func(function() {x.q()});
=> X {q: function}
```

I seem to be misunderstanding something about javascript because the way it behaves in this case is nothing like how I expect it to.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "this" keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the context (`this`) of a function is set by *how you call it* in JavaScript not *where it is declared* like some other languages.

So when you call a function like `f()` there is no context so it defaults to `window` but when you call it like `x.q()` the context is the `x` instance.

If I called a function like:

`obj.something.deep.property.func();`

In that case the context (`this`) of the function would be whatever `property` is.

(Note: that is strict mode if no context is determined `this` is `undefined`, not `window`)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of the context, `this`, is set when the function is ran, not when it's declared.

When you run `x.q()`, you are running `q()` in the "context" of the `x` object, so `this` inside `q()` is `x`.

When you pass `x.q()` to `func()` you are passing the function itself, not its context.  So when `func()` calls the function, its context is lost, so it's "defaulted" to `window` (the "global context").

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the context:

```
func(x.q.bind(x));
```

This is because when you just pass `x.q` all you are passing is the function:

```
function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

And the code has no idea what `this` refers to.