# What is difference between these two functions?

Tags: javascript

I have tried folllowing two ways of referring a function:

First

```
let a = function() {
   somefunction();
}
```

Second

```
let a = somefunction;
```

Where `somefunction` is the following in both cases:

```
function somefunction() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

Is there any difference between these two ways?

Comment: As shown, there's little difference (apart from the redundant intermediate function in the first case). However, from the way your `somefunction` is defined it looks like it's only the part of the story; why don't you show the real code here?

Comment: is `:` in `somefunction :function` a typo? You meant to write `=`?

Comment: May not be a typo. Could be an object literal.

Comment: @slebetman ok than explain `a=somefunction;` if an Object Literal was ment to be used

Comment: `var foo = {somefunction:function(){}};a=foo.somefunction` <-- he's probably just copying the js code from an object literal

Comment: One concrete example is when people try to do this: `var get = document.getElementById`. Then when they try to call `get(id)` they're surprised it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference between your two examples.

In the first case, you are defining a new anonymous (unnamed) function which calls `somefunction`. You are then assigning your new function definition to the variable `a`.  `a` holds a reference to your new function.

In the second case, you are simply assigning your original function of `somefunction` to the variable `a`.  The variable `a` then holds a reference to `somefunction`.  You are not creating a new function as you are in the first case.

Comment: And do these differ in functionality? )

Comment: @raina77ow no, they do not, however they are different.  The first is redundant and wastes memory.

Comment: To that I agree completely. The question is, should 'waste of memory' in this particular case be of so much trouble that it deserves to eventually morph into a SO question. ) Then again, the ways of OPs are puzzling sometimes.

Comment: Actually it differs in functionality as they might run in different scopes if you wrap your function inside an object, for example. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ARw3A/

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn Now I'm really curious why that is... Why would the act of calling `myFunction` from within another function use the object scope (which is not accessible from `a`)?

Comment: I don't know why the language designers chose to make JavaScript behave like this, but that's how it works. :P

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal

I guess I never realized the difference between invoking a function as a method and as a function when it comes to object literals.

Comment: That clarified some things to me too. Stack Overflow is a very interesting community. You can share your knowledge and learn more at the same time. :)

Comment: For a more complete description of how `this` works see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 3):

I think this example may make the difference clear. [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an array like object that contains each of the arguments passed to a function.

Try running each of these lines on your favorite browser console.

```
var somefunction = function() { console.log(arguments); };
```

Your first example demonstrates defining a named function `a` that [closes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) around the named function `somefunction`.

```
var a = function() { somefunction(); };
```

Your second example makes a reference, `b`, directly to `somefunction`.  This makes invoking `b` the same as invoking `somefunction`.

```
var b = somefunction;
```

Now if you call each of these `a` and `b` with some arguments you will see the difference.

```
=> a('a', 1);
[]

=> b('a', 1);
['a', 1]
```

In the first case the `arguments` object is empty.  That's because the arguments that were passed to `a` were not forwarded onto `somefunction`.

In the second case the arguments are available to `somefunction`, because some function is being called directly.

Here is how you could redefine `a` so that it were functionally equivalent using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
var a = function() { somefunction.apply(this, arguments); }
```

Running this at your console prints the argument array.

```
=> a('a', 1);
['a', 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = function(){
   somefunction();
}
```

Is an **Anonymous Function** attributed to `a` variable.

```
somefunction :function() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

Is an declaration of a function throungh the **Object Literal notation**.

The diference are shown when you are creating an object. **The anonymous function are not acessible as a "public" method**, instead in the Object Literal notation, that are acessible from outside.

As Douglas Crockford said, in JS the Good Parts, the first declaration are just a function and the second one could be a method.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are creating a function which calls `someFunction()`, then you assign that function to `a`, so now calling `a()` calls an anonymous function which in turn calls `someFunction()`.

In the second case, `a` and `someFunction` become the exact same thing, calling `a()` is the same as calling `someFunction()`.

Answer (score -1):

The way you're setting var `a` by accessing the function is clearly out of scope.
So I suspect you have a typo `:` instead of `=` :

```
var somefunction = function() {
  alert("hello");
};

somefunction(); // hello
```

...Now that your *first* and *second* makes sense with the code above:

**Anonymous Function** stored in variable:

```
var a = function(){
   alert('Hey');
   somefunction();
};
a(); // Hey // hello
```

**Variable as Function Reference**

```
var a = somefunction;
a(); // hello
```

---

In the other case than:

```
var objLiteral = {
  somefunction : function() {
      alert("hello");
  }
};

var a = objLiteral.somefunction;
a(); // hello
```