# Method from an object's instance doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute a method that's inside an object when you click a button, but apparently, it doesn't run. What am I doing wrong? I saw the variable "price" on Chrome's console, and it says "undefined" before and after pressing the button.

Javascript code:

```
function Upgrade () {
    this.buy = function(){
        this.price = 40;
    };
}

var upg = new Upgrade();

var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = upg.buy;
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <button id="button" type="button">Upgrade 1</button>
    <script src='newjavascript.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because as you are assigning your method directly to the `onclick` property, it will be fired with `this` being the DOM element.

You can make it work wrapping it into an anonymous function, so the `this` keyword will point to your own object.

```
button.onclick = function() {
    upg.buy();
}
```

Also, I suggest you to move your method to the prototype of your function.

```
function Upgrade () {
    this.price = 0;
}

Upgrade.prototype.buy = function() {
    this.price = 40;
}
```

Assigning it to prototype will make this method shared between all objects of your function, instead of creating a new copy for each one.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prVD9/

You can learn more about the `this` keyword behavior in this question: [How does "this" keyword work within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign function to object property, `this` refers to new object (`button` in your example).

Use this code instead:

```
function Upgrade () {
    var that = this;
    this.buy = function(){
        that.price = 40;
    };
}
```

or:

```
button.onclick = upg.buy.bind(upg);
```

I recommend to read MDN - [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).