# `this` inside function has nothing to do with a function?

Tags: javascript

```
var f2 = undefined
var f1 = function () {
    f2 = this
    console.log('here')
}
f1()
f2()
```

Outputs

```
f2()
^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How to set f2 to f1 from teh inside of f1() ?

Comment: First you didn't run `f1()`

Comment: No, calling f1() does not make it work for me.

Comment: `console.log(this)` then you'll know what `this` is.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually the right way to set it, but even if it was, you never called `f1`, so the value of `f2` could never change. You would need this:

```
var f2 = undefined;
var f1 = function () {
    f2 = this;
    console.log('here');
}
f1();
f2();
```

That said, the above still won't work, because `this` inside of a standalone function is not the function. In a browser, it will be the `window` object, and you'll get something like `TypeError: object is not a function`. In other contexts (e.g., node.js) it will depend on how they implement the top-level object, if any.

There is a [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) explaining how functions work with the `this` keyword. In this case you will not be able to do it without referring to the outer function by name or changing how you call `f1`:

```
// Referring to f1 by name..
var f2 = undefined;
var f1 = function () {
    f2 = f1;
    console.log('here');
}
f1();
f2();

// .. or using the apply method to change the value of "this", though still
// referring to f1 by name in some sense (at the call site)
var f2 = undefined;
var f1 = function () {
    f2 = this;
    console.log('here');
}
f1.apply(f1);
f2();
```

Side note, semicolon elision is gross.

Comment: Does this code work for you? Because I still get the same error. I use node.js here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any way to do it without a wrapper.

```
var wrapper = {}

wrapper.f1 = function () {
    wrapper.f2 = wrapper.f1
    console.log('invoked', this)
}

wrapper.f1()
wrapper.f2()
```

I'm not sure if that works in your actual use case or not.

```
var whatIsThis = function() {
    console.log('invoked', this)
}

whatIsThis()
```

On a related note, this second example shows the window object in a browser. I'm not sure what it will show in node.